# read number of charaters in HTML text using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

suppose i am getting HTML text in my  **JavaScript function** as

```
var TEMP= result.data;
```

where `result.data='<p>BODY&nbsp;Article By Archie(Used By Story Tool)</p>';`

i have done this:

```
            var e = document.createElement("span");
            e.innerHTML = TEMP;
            var text = e.innerText;
            var characterCount = text.length;                    
            var wordCount = text.match(/\b\w/g).length;
```

but this code doesn't work in mozilla firefox
i have also tried **o.k.w** s code but didn't work in mozilla

**and i also need the number of words**
i want to read the number of characters in TEMP,

and while doing that i want to skip **HTML tags** and html keywords (ex. `&nbsp;`)

pls help

**and important**  this should work on **mozilla firefox** browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested the codes below on IE8/FF3.5/Chrome.
`'<p>BODY&nbsp;Article By Archie(Used By Story Tool)</p>'` gives me charater count of 42.

```
function getCharCount(str){
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.innerHTML = str;
    if(d.textContent) //for FF and DOM3 compliant
        alert(d.textContent.length);
    else if(d.innerText) //for IE and others
        alert(d.innerText.length);
    else
        alert("0");
}
```

Comment: Requisite reference on this trick you're doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359822#1359822

Comment: Ah, I didn't know of that post. Thanks for the reference :)

Comment: I'd test for `textContent` first as it is the DOM 3 Core standard method. Also, better to use `if ('innerText' in d)` to check for the existence of the property as testing directly on the value will fail if the text is an empty string (which is falsy in JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (this is using jQuery, but the same can be done without it):

```
var element = $('<p>BODY&nbsp;Article By Archie(Used By Story Tool)</p>');
var length = element.get(0).textContent.length;
```

You will get the length of text without tags or HTML entities

Comment: thanks for reply but i have an issue that
the html text would be bind to an object 

eg. var element= result.data;
and now element will have html inside 
how to implement this ?

Comment: If I get it right, you want to create an element from an HTML code that you get from a response. In that case you just do it the same way: `var element = $('<div>' + result.data + '</div>');` The `div` wrapping is just to be sure that you have a single element wrapping all your code.