# innerText/textContent vs. retrieving each text node

Tags: javascript, dom

I've heard that using `el.innerText||el.textContent` can yield unreliable results, and that's why I've always insisted on using the following function in the past:

```
function getText(node) {

    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        return node.data;
    }

    var txt = '';

    if (node = node.firstChild) do {
        txt += getText(node);
    } while (node = node.nextSibling);

    return txt;

}
```

This function goes through all nodes within an element and gathers the text of all text nodes, and text within descendants:

E.g.

```
<div id="x">foo <em>foo...</em> foo</div>
```

Result:

```
getText(document.getElementById('x')); // => "foo foo... foo"
```

I'm *quite* sure there are issues with using `innerText` and `textContent`, but I've not been able to find a definitive list anywhere and I am starting to wonder if it's just *hearsay*.

Can anyone offer any information about the possibly lacking reliability of textContent/innerText?

**EDIT**: Found this great answer by Kangax -- ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359822#1359822)

Comment: So simple and so useful!
How about `document.TEXT_NODE` instead of `3`?
Is that not supported in older browsers?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's all about endlines and whitespace - browsers are very inconsistent in this regard, especially so in Internet Explorer. Doing the traversal is a sure-fire way to get identical results in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm surprised that there's pretty much no mention of this problem elsewhere on the net... even QuirksMode doesn't mention it.

Comment: Traversal doesn't guarantee the same results in all browsers. For example, in IE (unlike other browsers) the content of a `<script>` element is not represented as a text node in the DOM.