# Make a DIV act as an INPUT field

Tags: javascript, html, input, textfield

I am currently using a bunch of input textfields and I want to change it to a DIV, but most of my JS functions use `document.getElementById("inputField1").value` whenever the value of the input field is set like this:

```
<input contenteditable="false" id="inputField1" type="text" size="12" style="background:#09F;color:#FFF;text-align:center" value="Hello World!"/>
```

That would return just `Hello World!` if I were to display the value in an `alert`

How would I get the value of the text in between if I were to use DIVs?

For example `<div id="inField001">Hello World</div>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that case you can use:

```
document.getElementById('inField001').innerHTML
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById('inField001').innerText
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById('inField001').textContent
```

Also (if you want to use jQuery):

```
$('#inField001').text()
```

Answer (score 5):

You would just do

```
var value = document.getElementById('inField001').innerHTML);
```

But if your DIV has some html this will grab that too.

[.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

You can also use `document.getElementById('inField001').textContent)` to grab just the text nodes from the element ignoring any element wrappers.

But support for textContent is not as good as innerHTML.
See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) for info and support.

Another way is using `innerText`. `alert(document.getElementById('inField001').innerText);` but not supported in FF.

See [Doc](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html) for support.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hdb7D/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the innerHTML property.

```
document.getElementById("inField001").innerHTML
```

BTW this kind of thing is way better to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

For just text content:

```
var value = document.getElementById('inputField1').textContent;
```

For the more verbose version, [see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653670/innertext-textcontent-vs-retrieving-each-text-node)

Answer (score -1):

or just do

```
x = document.getElementById("inField001");
alert(x);
```