# javascript/ajax help needed

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I get the document object out of this?

```
var xmlobject = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlstring, "text/xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `xmlobject` **is** the document object, [according to MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser). According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp), on IE, you need to use an IE-specific ActiveX object instead of `DOMParser`:

```
var xmlDoc, parser;
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
}
else { // Internet Explorer
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async="false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(text); 
}
```

You've said that `getElementById` isn't working. Note that `id` is not a special attribute (an attribute of type "ID") in XML by default, so even if you're giving elements an `id` attribute, `getElementById` won't work (it should return `null`). Details in the [W3C docs for `getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId). I've never done it, but I assume you'd assign an attribute the "ID" type via a DTD.

Without one, though, you can use other traversal mechanisms. For example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/iwiti5)):

```
var xmlDoc, parser, text, things, index, thing;

text =
    '<test>' +
    '<thing>Thing 1</thing>' +
    '<thing>Thing 2</thing>' +
    '</test>';
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
}
else { // Internet Explorer
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async="false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(text); 
}
things = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('thing');
for (index = 0; index < things.length; ++index) {
    thing = things.item(index);
    display(index + ": " + getText(thing));
}
```

...where `getText` is:

```
function getText(element) {
    return textCollector(element, []).join("");
}
function textCollector(element, collector) { 
    for (node = element.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) { 
        switch (node.nodeType) { 
            case 3: // text 
            case 4: // cdata 
            collector.push(node.nodeValue); 
            break; 
          case 8: // comment 
              break; 
          case 1: // element 
            if (node.tagName == 'SCRIPT') { 
                break; 
            } 
            // FALL THROUGH TO DEFAULT 
            default: 
            // Descend 
            textCollector(node, collector); 
            break; 
        } 
    }
    return collector;
}
```

(`getText` is a good example of why I use libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) for this stuff. You'd think it would be simple to get the text inside an element, and it **is** if the element has exactly one text node inside it [as our `thing`s do above]. If it doesn't, well, [it gets complicated fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359822#1359822).)

Comment: hmmmm....i was not able to invoke methods like getElementById etc...thts why,...guess there is something else wrong...

Comment: @Arun: You may be looking for `xmlDoc.documentElement` -- I'll work up a quick example.

Comment: @Arun: I've added an example.

Comment: @Arun: ...and a note about why `getElementById`, specifically, may not have been working for you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:ok cool....my problem was that there an invalid xml returned by my platform so i kinda had to get the response in string itself and iterate through and fetch only the respective div i needed and assigned and innerHTML to the div that needed the replacement...thnks buddy...

Comment: @Arun: *Ouch* Well, in any case, glad that helped.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: one more doubt clearTimeOut() method does not work for me in the platform that i am working on...it works fine when i am trying in a browser...w3schools example..any idea wat could be causing this?

Comment: @Arun: Best to ask new questions as questions. `clearTimeout` (note the capitalization, it matters in JavaScript) should be provided by all implementations that support the timer functions of the `window` object. Of course, JavaScript is not limited to browsers, and so it's perfectly valid to have a JavaScript environment that doesn't have `setTimeout`, `clearTimeout`, etc. In that case, if the environment doesn't provide something equivalent, you're out of luck -- there's no way to do it with JavaScript on its own without help from the environment.