# How to get text content of the entire document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building Chrome extension which at some point should determine current page language. In order to do that, my plan is to extract text content of the page (or at least a part of it) and pass it to translation api. However I couldn't find any strait forward way to just get all `textNode`s of the document.

There is a backup plan which is to recursively analyze `$('body').contents()` until there is enough text content, but it feels a bit flaky. Perhaps there is a better way?

Note: Chrome extensions api allows your script to access user page dom as if it was the part of it.

Comment: is there way you could use python executables in chrome-extension development? If so you can use `SGMLParser` from `sgmllib` module to achieve that! not very sure how to do this using js

Comment: what do you do with the complete html of page???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [jQuery text() method](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$('body').text()
```

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but you want: `$('body').text()`

Answer (score 31):

Javascript:

```
document.body.textContent
```

Comment: For me, in 2021 on Chrome, this gets a lot more than just the text. A quick test of this on wikipedia, for example, manages to extract a lot of CSS & code in addition to the text on the page. `document.body.innerText`, however, works cleanly.

Comment: Here is some info about `innerText`, `textContent` and the differences: [HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText), [textContent and innerText differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)

Answer (score 18):

Without jQuery, just as easy: `document.body.innerText;`

Comment: innerText for IE only, document.body.textContent otherwise

Comment: According to PPK, both are more or less cross-browser (innerText being absent in Firefox, textContent in IE) http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Comment: They're different though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359822#1359822

Comment: innerText is now implemented in all browsers. It works great and I'd recommend it. See https://caniuse.com/innertext. Many tutorials are still outdated and mention its lack of compatibility, but, no longer!

Answer (score 1):

VanillaJS:

```
document.body.outerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chrome.tabs.detectLanguage(integer tabId, function callback)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-detectLanguage).

Answer (score 0):

all these methods return undefined when attempted in the console with chrome.

```
var text = document.body.textContent;
var text = document.body.outerHTML;
var text = document.body.innerText;
```

etc ...

Comment: The statement itself, `var text = document.body.innerText;` will return undefined, just as the statement `var i = 5;` will return undefined.

Simply type `document.body.innerText` in the console and you will see the output.