# javascript get html or text from div

Tags: javascript, image, json, api

This is easy in jquery but how about plain javascript?

The code is for the Google image search API. I want to search images that match the html or preferably text inside a div.

```
var searchThis = document.getElementById('imgToFind'); //get HTML, or text from div

// Find images
imageSearch.execute(searchThis); //search image
```

The HTML

```
<div id="imgToFind">PlayStation</div>
```

The result should be images of playstation. Instead I get these

[image: 1] dosic ois - 123

[image] IE8 javascript returns [object HTMLDivElement] instead [

[image] Loving Hand

And other irrelevant images. I wonder what Google searches for.. think the second one is giving me a hint.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

its `var searchThis = document.getElementById('imgToFind').innerHTML;`

to extract only text you can do:

```
element = document.getElementById('imgToFind');
var searchThis = element.textContent || element.innerText;
```

Comment: THX! is there such a thing as `.text()` like in jquery?

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use plain js because the google api doesn't use jquery. Thought I would do everything in one script. I just need a few simple functions.

Comment: No, you don't need a parser to extract the text from a DOM element. You can use the element's `textContent` or `innerText` property as per my answer or traverse the DOM and amalgamate text from each text node encountered. It's not that hard and doesn't require jQuery.

Comment: @Tim: Thanks to enlight me. I dint know that.

Answer (score 5):

`var searchThis = document.getElementById('imgToFind').innerHTML;`

will grab the contents of the element :)

Comment: Thx! Seems like you answered at the same time lol. Will vote person who answers bonus question. Is there such a thing as `.text()` in javascript like there is in jquery?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure about that one honestly :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the text within an element, you can use `textContent` in the more standards compliant browsers (i.e. not IE) and `innerText` in IE. [They're not identical in all cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359822#1359822) but for your purposes they may well be.

```
var el = document.getElementById("foo");
var text = el.textContent || el.innerText;
```