# Js function running fine on Chrome, but not on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, prototypejs

I'm trying to make some of the components in my list interactive, as there're many comments and settings depending on the user's input on the form.

The product is made out of several components, each one with their own properties, however, the product validation relies on some of the components values chosen.

I have the following js function which gets called from my view:

```
function change_people() {
  money1 = $('money_1').children[0].value;
  if (money1 == 5) {
      $('comment_2').innerText = "sss";
      //$('comment_2').hide();
  } 
  else {
      $('comment_2').innerText = "";
      //$('comment_2').show();
  }
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  change_people();
  $('money_1').children[0].observe('change', change_people);
});
```

When I run the code in chrome, it works fine, with each selection it will update the next comment, however, in firefox is completely unresponsive!

Anyone got ideas of the reasons for this?

(oh and is using prototype library)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerText` is the Microsoft version of the standard `textContent`. Chrome supports both, but Firefox only the standard one. There are two things you can do:

**1.** Dummy test (executed only once) *[keep in mind the gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359822#1359822)*

```
var textContent = (function() { 
  var dummy = document.createElement("span");
  dummy.innerHTML = "full <span>support</span>";
  if (dummy.textContent === "full support") {
     return "textContent";
  } else {
     return "innerText";
  }
})();
```

*usage*

```
el[textContent] = "text";
```

**2.** Use DOM methods

```
function setText(el, text) {
    while (el.firstChild) {
        el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
    }
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
}
```

*usage*

```
setText(el, "text");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! You're a star!

Comment: I've also added feature detection, in case you wanna support IE.

Comment: Note that `innerText` and `textContent` are *not quite* the same thing, there are real gotchas in there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359822#1359822

Comment: Thanks! yes, will need IE as well.

Comment: @TJ - Yep I was about to add that link.

Comment: @Lievcin: For *getting* the text content, you might find this thread (and the associated code) useful: http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-scriptaculous/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-04/2ba484c64057a926

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to use [Element.update](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/update/).

```
$('comment_2').update((money1 == 5) ? 'sss' : '');
```