# Jquery Ui Autocomplete - How to remove the html from the selected value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using the jquery ui autocomplete plugin in my page.

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
            //source: sampleData(),
              source: function(request, response) {
              response(data(request.term));

        },


    enter code here
            minLength: 3,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                //alert(ui.item.label);

                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
```

The response call back gets a string array as its return value.
the string is of this sample  format ..Akola,India-Akola(AKD)
The suggestion list comes up fine with the actual rendered from the string.
But when I select the value the value gets defaulted to the actual html string.
How do I make the selected value to have only the string and not the html ?

Item.label and Item.value remain the same..label shows up fine in suggestion..
but I need to  make the item.value contain only the string.

Thanks
Yogesh

Answer (score 0):

try using this.value.text() or else refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string) question. you may have to play around a little to parse the HTML but these options should work

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work you should also pass **item.value**

On select it looks for  **item.value** first and then for  **item.label**

That way you can leave your select: like that

```
select: function( event, ui ) {

    }
```