# remove a set of characters from a script

Tags: javascript

How to remove `<p>` and `</p>` from a text in javascript?

I have a string

```
 <p> This is a text</p>
```

and I want to remove the  `<p>` and the `</p>`.

How can I do that in Javascript?

Comment: If you can't use jQuery: [JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5002111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function.

For example: `"<p> This is a text</p>".replace(/<\/?p>/g,"")`.

Comment: Your replacement needle needs to be a regular expression: `/<p\/?>/`

Comment: And the `/` was on the wrong side of the `p`. And it didn't have the `g` switch. One of those days...