# android: declare huge string in strings.xml

Tags: android, string

i have a very huge HTML string in my app.

When I use it in the code, everything is fine but when I try to declare it in strings.xml, I am getting some errors. Is there a way to make a simple copy of the string in strings.xml? Thank you

Comment: "Some errors." Not terribly helpful. Is it in a CDATA?

Comment: why don't you put the string in a file in assets folder?

Comment: @gabi, how can i do this? in text file, how to open it then?

Comment: AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("myfile.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());

Comment: Thank you @gabi, but what to do with the file reader?

Comment: with file reader you can read files... so you can read your huge content from your file.

Comment: Ah ok, I have only to do reader.toString(); right? Thank you

Comment: I have a problem @gabi, i can't use getAssets(). I am in a non activity class,I have tryed: context.getAssets().openFd("myFile.txt"); but in is not working (), i am getting an exception.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10046/discussion-between-ana-and-gabi)

Comment: I am using it but the problem is that I have a file not found exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML and XML are the same basic language, I do not believe that you can store HTML in a string, why not save the html page and package it with the application?

---

Save the page as a html page in res > raw and then call this method

```
 String html = Utils.readRawTextFile(ctx, R.raw.rawhtml);

 public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId)
     {
          InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

             ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

             int i;
              try {
               i = inputStream.read();
               while (i != -1)
                  {
                   byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                   i = inputStream.read();
                  }
                  inputStream.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  return null;
              }
                 return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
     }
```

Comment: Thank you @SmartLemon, how can I do this

Comment: Sweet as :D, gotta use it myself now :P

Answer (score 1):

Error may come at special characters like `@` `double quote` `single quote` etc. to overcome it prefix `\` to it and your error get resolved

if you assign same string programmatically there also you will find the same issue

```
String mString= "your huge string with @ error";
```

in this also you have to overcome be prefixing backslash

```
 String mString= "your huge string with \@ error";
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to explain that there is no errors when using it in a local variable?

Comment: there will be no error in local variable, as in JAVA code.. u dont need to escape single quote, but u have to do it in XML.

Comment: How is this going to work if he has a huge string? Shouldn't you just save the html page?

Comment: If you are going to do this use find and replace

find @ and replace with \@ 
would be waaay fastr

Comment: Also HTML contains things like /> which wouldnt work in xml because it will take it as a end.

Comment: about string contain "<" "</>" have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099941/how-to-remove-unwanted-characters-in-a-string/10099969#10099969