# How to strip HTML tags with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to remove HTML tags from a string. For example assume we have the string:

```
 <p> example ive got a string</P>
```

How can I write a function that removes the `<p><p>` and returns just "example ive got a string"?

Comment: a quick google would find you this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string which is itself a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The **safest way** is to rely on the browser TextNode to correctly escape content. Here's an example:

```js
function encodeHTML(dirtyString) {
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  var text = document.createTextNode(dirtyString);
  container.appendChild(text);
  return container.innerHTML; // innerHTML will be a xss safe string
}

document.write( encodeHTML('<p>some <span>content</span></p>') );
document.write( encodeHTML('<script><p>some <span>content</span></p>') );
```

The thing to remember here is that the browser escape the special characters of TextNodes when we access the html strings (`innerHTML`, `outerHTML`). By comparison, accessing text values (`innerText`, `textContent`) will yield raw strings, meaning they're unsafe and could contains XSS.

If you use **jQuery**, then using `.text()` is safe and backward compatible. See the other answers to this question.

The **simplest way** in pure JavaScript if you work with browsers <= Internet Explorer 8 is:

```
string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

But there's some issue with parsing HTML with regex so this won't provide very good security. Also, this only takes care of HTML characters, so it is not totally xss-safe.

Comment: Trying to strip HTML with regexes is a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: @ymln this is long overdue, but I updated the answer with way more details and a secure way to extract text without jQuery.

Comment: This seems to break if you put in an unclosed '<script>' tag. e.g. `console.log( stripHTML('<script><p>some <span>content</span></p>') );` will return `'<p>some <span>content</span></p>'`

Comment: @MatthewWilcoxson took me a while to come back here, but here is the answer fixed. Hopefully without any other edge cases.

Comment: puls 1 for XSS safe way.

Comment: Technically the regex version is the one that does what the asker wants... removes the tags and returns just "example ive got a string". The other version leaves the tags present but makes the text not vulnerable to XSS it isn't actually "stripHTML". I wanted to point out though anti xss code can be done safely with jquery e.g. `return $('<div/>').text(stringToFormat).text();`

Comment: The provided function stripHTML doesn't strip HTML, it html-encodes special characters.

Comment: Question was Jquery not with browser. Now your answer is 1000 years old and is no longer that usefull for node users. grrr

Comment: OP was clear about wanting the text WITHOUT the tags. this escapes everything to be HTML safe not stripping anything, it show `<p> example ive got a string</p>` on screen instead but OP asked for `example ive got a string`.

Comment: If this function is used on, say, a textarea change event, it will keep escaping entities, including turning & into &amp; and then into &amp;amp; and then &amp;&amp;amp;
You'll definitely want to use the text only version instead of this encoding version for repeat use.

Comment: -1 I don't normally downvote answers, but I actually invested my time trying this out only to find out it encodes rather than strips html. I would NOT have downvoted if the answer had stated this and/or properly named the function "encodeHTML" rather than "stripHTML".

Answer (score 145):

Use the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function:

```
var text = $("<p> example ive got a string</P>").text();
```

**Update**: As Brilliand points out below, if the input string does not contain any tags and you are unlucky enough, it might be treated as a CSS selector. So this version is more robust:

```
var text = $("<div/>").html("<p> example ive got a string</P>").text();
```

Comment: Is this completely reliable? While it strips tags, it seems to execute any javascript inserted into an onLoad attribute of that tag if the tag supports that attribute. For example, if you use the string <img src="some_real_image.jpg" onLoad="alert('hi');"> , the javascript executes when running this to strip its tags.

Comment: @Nile: jQuery does this by creating DOM nodes and getting their pure-text values (effectively letting the browser do the hard work), so scripts will be executed if appropriate. There's no way to prevent this AFAIK.

Comment: When working with a dynamic content, in case the content is a plain text, not an html, this will cause error. So I use `$('<span>'+content+'</span>').text();`

Comment: You really don't want to do this unless you know the source of the data is safe. An example of why this is the case is because if the string is "<script>alert('hello');</script>" then it runs the script. Making it vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: @vipero07, in my testing it does not run the script. The `<script>` tags are stripped and you're just left with `alert('hello');`

Answer (score 4):

This is a example for get the url image, escape the p tag from some item.

Try this:

```
$('#img').attr('src').split('<p>')[1].split('</p>')[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the innerHTML of the element and only strip the outermost tag, you can do this:

```
$(".contentToStrip").each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the existing split function

One easy and choppy exemple:

```
var str = '<p> example ive got a string</P>';
var substr = str.split('<p> ');
// substr[0] contains ""
// substr[1] contains "example ive got a string</P>"
var substr2 = substr [1].split('</p>');
// substr2[0] contains "example ive got a string"
// substr2[1] contains ""
```

The example is just to show you how the split works.