# If page contains specific text then reload (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, greasekit, fluid-mac-app-engine

If the text `We are sorry but we made a boo boo` appears then

1. Wait 5 seconds
2. reload

I would like to do this in JavaScript.

Here is an attempt

```
(function () {
"use strict";

function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
    if (node && node.nodeType) {
        if (typeof func === "function") {
            func(node);
        }

        node = node.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            walkTheDOM(node, func);
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
}

function filterElementsByContains(elements, string) {
    var toStringFN = {}.toString,
        text = toStringFN.call(elements),
        result,
        length,
        i,
        element;

    if (text !== "[object NodeList]" && text !== "[object Array]" && !($() instanceof jQuery)) {
        return result;
    }

    result = [];
    if (typeof string === "string") {
        string = new RegExp("^" + string + "$");
    } else if (toStringFN.call(string) !== "[object RegExp]") {
        return result;
    }

    function getText(node) {
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            text += node.nodeValue;
        }
    }

    length = elements.length;
    i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        text = "";
        element = elements[i];
        walkTheDOM(element, getText);
        if (string.test(text)) {
            result.push(element);
        }

        i += 1;
    }

    return result;
}

if(filterElementsByContains([document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]], /We are sorry but we made a boo boo/).length) {
    location.reload();
}
```

The above could should, I think, work for the text if it appears in a specific place. I want to make it more general - so that the text could appear **anywhere** on that page.

Also, I would like to know how to add a pause so that, for example, it waits 5 seconds before reloading.

I guess I would add incorporate something like:

```
setTimeout(
function() 
{
//location.reload();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I would recommend you use a div with an id to check for that text, not the hole html document.

Comment: Have you tried $("html").html()?

Comment: @ctwheels, that would include the html tags, which would cause a problem if part of the text has tags in it, ie: `We are sorry but we <span>made</span> a <span>boo boo</span>`. thought using `.text()` would get the text without tags

Comment: @PatrickEvans You can use regex to remove the tags from the document: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140043/how-to-strip-html-tags-with-jquery

Comment: yes but why bother when you can just use a function that already gets text without html tags, and i counter that answer with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/560593

Comment: @PatrickEvans well then `$("html").text()`

Comment: Yes as stated in my earlier comment, the .text() would work...

Comment: Well then my apologies, yes as you stated earlier, .text() would work in his case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do an [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) on the body's [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)/[innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899(v=vs.85).aspx) property

```
var content = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
var hasText = content.indexOf("We are sorry but we made a boo boo")!==-1;
if(hasText){
   setTimeout(function(){
       window.location = "http://www.example.com";
   },5000);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the `example.com` thing? I would like it to reload the current page, rather than go to a specific (predefined) URL.

Comment: @JohnSmith, its just an example, to reload just do `window.location.reload()`

Comment: I have just noticed an alternative way of phrasing the error message: `There was an internal error in our system. We logged the problem and will investigate it later.` Please could someone help me: I'd like to add this rule to the existing answer

Answer (score 3):

This may work:

```
var bodyText = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
var msg = "We are sorry but we made a boo boo";

if (bodyText.indexOf(msg) > -1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
    }, 5000);
}
```

--sorry for nearly duplicate answer :\ --

--edit--

> Tell me - how can I add a second rule, it's a different way of
>   phrasing the error message: There was an internal error in our system.
>   We logged the problem and will investigate it later.

This will check for both messages:

```
var bodyText = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
var msg = [
    "We are sorry but we made a boo boo",
    "There was an internal error in our system. We logged the problem and will investigate it later."
];

var flag = false;

for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
    if bodyText.indexOf(msg[i]) {
        flag = true;
    }
}

if (flag) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
    }, 5000);   
}
```

Explanation:  All I did was modify `msg` to be an array of strings rather than a string itself.  Then for every `msg` we want to check, we loop through the values and compare `msg` against `bodyText`.  If `bodyText` contains one of the `msg`'s, we set a `flag` to `true`, and then perform an if statement on `flag`.

Comment: Always good to see a second way of doing things. Tell me - how can I add a second rule, it's a different way of phrasing the error message: `There was an internal error in our system. We logged the problem and will investigate it later.`

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to check anywhere in the page... then you have to do just that. Get every DOM element and check if there is your String there... I do not think there is another way.
2. Yes using setTimeout will do the trick for waiting before reload.