# How to split html tags in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider, this is some response data I got from Ajax.

```
<table width=100%><tr><td>This content is applicable for users.
</td</tr><tr><td align='center'><button class='btn' onclick='hidethis();'
 type='button'>OK</button></td</tr></table>
```

Here, I need to get only the contents `This content is applicable for users.` by splitting the html tags. Normally, we use like

```
var tokens = this.value.split(" ");
```

Based on Array `tokens[0], tokens[1]`, we will get the values.
How can I get the values by splitting html `<table>` tags.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
I want to use only jquery to achieve this. And it should be simplified.

Comment: Isnt it normally done by traversing ?

Comment: use `DOM` instead of string manipulation...

Comment: How??? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you have received the data as string, you can create the constructor and then get required text from first td element:

```
var response="<table width=100%><tr><td>This content is applicable for users.</td</tr><tr><td align='center'><button class='btn' onclick='hidethis();' type='button'>OK</button></td</tr></table>";
var tdcontent=$(response).find('td:eq(0)').text();
```

**NOTE:** You need to reformat the DOM to make above solution work. you have broken html in string. td elements are not closed properly.

Comment: Working like a charm!

Comment: Why duplicate? It is more simply right when compare to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140043/how-to-strip-html-tags-with-jquery