# How to escape HTML from text input .val() with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I am capturing the text input of a form using `.val()`:

```
$newItem = $('input[type=text]').val();
```

The problem is that `.val()` will preserve any html-tags, which will be applied in the DOM if I am appending the variable.

What is the recommended, safe way to escape HTML-input and just use the text value?

Comment: Use `text()` to add the variable to a DOM element - assuming you want to HTMLEncode the value, not strip out the HTML completely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to strip HTML tags with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140043/how-to-strip-html-tags-with-jquery)

Comment: Why is this downvoted? OP has given an description of the issue and asked a legitimate question.

Comment: Duplicate and it was answered [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)

Comment: I see that this could be related to the suggested question. However, there are serious critics about the recommend [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery).

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
$("<div>").text($('input[type=text]').val()).html()
```

Result:

```
aby&lt;d
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/851964/

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$newItem = $($('input[type=text]').val()).text();
```

Comment: $($(this).val()).text(); Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: aby<d
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.3.1.js:1541)
    at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery-3.3.1.js:2193)
    at Sizzle.select (jquery-3.3.1.js:2620)
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-3.3.1.js:845)
    at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery-3.3.1.js:2873)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-3.3.1.js:2983)
    at jQuery (jquery-3.3.1.js:139)

Comment: @alexqc error comes from value you are trying to parse

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to encode html character from input containing text "aby<d", and jquery fails using this $($(this).val()).text(); approach to encode.