# Is it possible to remove all anchor tags from a paragraph using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I would like to remove all anchor tags from a paragraph using jQuery while keeping the text. Is this possible?

For example I would like jQuery to turn this:

```
<p>content content content content content content
   <a href="#">link</a> content content content content
   <a href="#">link</a> content content content content 
   <a href="#">link</a> content content content content</p>
```

Into this:

```
 <p>content content content content content content
    link content content content content
    link content content content content 
    link content content content content</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140043/how-to-strip-html-tags-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
jQuery("p").find("a").contents().unwrap();
```

Sorry I should of done more research before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the anchors with the text they contain

```
$('p a').replaceWith(function() {
    return document.createTextNode($(this).text())
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("p a").contents().unwrap();
    
    
})
```

```html
<p>content content content content content content
   <a href="#">link</a> content content content content
   <a href="#">link</a> content content content content 
   <a href="#">link</a> content content content content
</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```