# Strip formatting from link but not text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need my website to display an address and link to that same address on Google Maps.

The CMS is outputting formatted text so it looks good on the page (with paragraph and break tags), but I need to strip these out in the href so it links correctly.

In other words, I'm outputting something like this:

```
<p>Address Line 1<br>
Address line 2<br>
City, State, Zip</p>
```

But I need a link around this text that uses the same output from the CMS, but strips the HTML tags from it. So, something like this:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=Address Line 1, Address Line 2 City, State, Zip"</a>
```

I have been able to strip the tags and replace them with spaces, but then it also strips them from the formatted text within the link. I haven't been able to *only* strip the tags from the  and not the formatted text within the link.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it with [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

**HTML:**

```
<p id="address">Address Line 1<br>
Address line 2<br>
City, State, Zip</p>
<a id="gMapLink" href="http://maps.google.com/?q=Address Line 1, Address Line 2 City, State, Zip"</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var address = $('#address').html(),
        link = 'http://maps.google.com/?q=',
        addressStripped = address.replace(/<br>/g, ',');

    $('#gMapLink').prop('href', link + addressStripped);
    console.log(addressStripped, $('a').prop('href'))
});
```

See JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/danielgasser/3onteLqq/).

Comment: Thanks! I was using .attr() instead of .prop(), but I don't know why else mine wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried $().text() and encodeURIComponent?

```js
$('.Result').html(encodeURIComponent($('.req').text()))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="req"><span>abc,<span>eef</span></span></div>

<div class="Result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it's your second line, where you do the replaceWith... At that point 'address' is just a text string, so really you'd want to just use plain old javascript regular expression on it:

```
var strippedAddress = address.replace(/[\r\n]{1,2}/g, ' ');
```

and that should do it!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean in jquery, from your tags, so I think this is a duplicate of [How to strip HTML tags with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13140043/4735256)

... and if you really want commas to replace your line breaks, you can do a string replace for \n characters which is the character for line breaks

Comment: Hi. I can strip HTML fine, but only doing so from the link and not the text was the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before, I just did a google search for 'javascript remove html tags from string' and found a number of ways (most of them on stackOverflow...)

You might try something like: 
`var html = "<p>Some HTML</p>";
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;
var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";`

The textContent and the innerText do similar but not the same things. I'd research them and find the one that is best for you.

Comment: I'm able to remove html tags from a string, but I was having trouble keeping those tags in the text, but removing them from the link only. I googled as well, and wasn't able to find anything that I could use successfully.