# Show the ajax' response in pure text and html format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, text

I would like to build a forward proxy on my local pc with apache, So far I wrote a simple cross-domain demo with proxy locally.

Here is the `/var/www/html/client.html` file:

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
function Ajax( ) {
     var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/do.php?url=http://127.0.0.1/test.html';
      $.ajax(url, {
        type:"GET",
        dataType: 'html',
        crossDomain: true,
            success:function(response){  
                mytext = document.getElementById("remote");
                mytext.append(response);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("error");
            }    
      });
};
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="show content" onclick="Ajax();">    
    <p id="remote">the content on remote webpage</p>
```

Here is the `/var/www/html/do.phpdo.php` file, it function as a proxy, get target url:

```
/var/www/html/test.html
```

and send as `remote` (showed in client.html), callback into `client.html`.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
?>
```

The  `/var/www/html/test.html` file:

```
<p><b>you are welcome</b></p>
```

To input `127.0.0.1/client.html` in browser and click button `show content`, what I get is the following:

```
the content on remote webpage<p><b>you are welcome</b></p>
```

I want the response callbacked into `client.html` from  `do.php`, showed in two kinds of format:

1. **showed as pure text format.**

   ```
   mytext.append(response.responseText);
   ```

   It is my try, failure.
   The result what i expect in pure text format is:

   ```
   the content on remote webpage
   you are welcome
   ```
2. **showed as html format.**
   What I expect  html format:

[image]

What I get format with my code:

```
the content on remote webpage<p><b>you are welcome</b></p>
```

How do I fix my code `mytext.append(response);`, maybe here, for the two cases?

Comment: I have no clue what your issue is exactly.

Comment: You are not  accustomed to broken  english .

Comment: SO you just want the text without HTML markup?

Comment: "You are not accustomed to broken english" I been on this site for 10 years, I have no issues with broken English. I just have no clue what your problem is exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the two issue based on jquery's append method ,instead of javascript's append method in my privious code.

1.pure text format

```
mytext = $("#remote");
mytext.append("<br/>");
mytext.append($(response).text());
```

2.html format

```
mytext = $("#remote");
mytext.append("<br/>");
mytext.append(response);
```

In javascript, ParentNode.append() allows  to   append DOMString object.
[ParentNode.append() in js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

```
mytext = document.getElementById("remote");
mytext.append(response);
```

The two lines above result in the following as output.

```
content on remote webpage<p><b>you are welcome</b></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. To get the html format, your code is OK,
2. If yu want to get the pure text format use the jQuery(...).text() function to remove html tags from the response.

   ```
   ...
   mytext = document.getElementById("remote");
   mytext.append($(response).text());
   ...
   ```

Have a look at: [How to strip HTML tags with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140043/how-to-strip-html-tags-with-jquery)

Comment: The right code show result as `the content on remote webpage<p><b>you are welcome</b></p>` ,not in html format.

Comment: what is append() with DOM?