# Using a website with JavaScript to scrape HTML source code

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to use basic JavaScript to get HTML source code from a website? HELP!

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: To create a self-building website. I need it to get reference websites.

Comment: You might want to look into curl. Just google it, lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151473/show-the-ajax-response-in-pure-text-and-html-format)

1. Perform an ajax request
2. Print the response as text