# Prevent downloading images when creating a substring of text node with img tags

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous

I'm doing an asynchronous call an Wordpress REST API endpoint.  I'm creating a news area with a list of article excerpts and thumbnails.  The client didn't put excerpts on all their posts, so I intended to simply use the post content and restrict the content with a substring.

What I want is the first 75 characters of the post.content.rendered without HTML and without downloading the image(s) at the end of the text.

Example of API response:

```
{  
   "id":29,
   "date":"2019-01-09T14:06:55",
   "date_gmt":"2019-01-09T14:06:55",
   "guid":{  
      "rendered":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/?page_id=29"
   },
   "modified":"2019-01-09T14:06:55",
   "modified_gmt":"2019-01-09T14:06:55",
   "slug":"home-page",
   "status":"publish",
   "type":"page",
   "link":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/home-page/",
   "title":{  
      "rendered":"Home Page"
   },
   "content":{  
      // Dont want the image at the end to be downloaded by
      // the browser, just want the first 75 characters.
      "rendered":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
                  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
                  enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
                  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
                  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
                  pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 
                  in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>\n
                  <p><img src="some/path/to/file.jpg" /></p>\n",
      "protected":false
   },
   "excerpt":{  
      "rendered":"",
      "protected":false
   },
   "author":1,
   "featured_media":0,
   "parent":0,
   "menu_order":0,
   "comment_status":"closed",
   "ping_status":"closed",
   "template":"",
   "meta":[  

   ],
   "better_featured_image":null,
   "acf":[  

   ],
   "_links":{  
      "self":[  
         {  
            "href":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/29"
         }
      ],
      "collection":[  
         {  
            "href":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages"
         }
      ],
      "about":[  
         {  
            "href":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/types/page"
         }
      ],
      "author":[  
         {  
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
         }
      ],
      "replies":[  
         {  
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=29"
         }
      ],
      "version-history":[  
         {  
            "count":1,
            "href":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/29/revisions"
         }
      ],
      "predecessor-version":[  
         {  
            "id":30,
            "href":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/29/revisions/30"
         }
      ],
      "wp:attachment":[  
         {  
            "href":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=29"
         }
      ],
      "curies":[  
         {  
            "name":"wp",
            "href":"https://api.w.org/{rel}",
            "templated":true
         }
      ]
   },
   "_embedded":{  
      "author":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"overlord",
            "url":"",
            "description":"",
            "link":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/author/overlord/",
            "slug":"overlord",
            "avatar_urls":{  
               "24":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d1451cce55fa940546c99221f3c3cb48?s=24&d=mm&r=g",
               "48":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d1451cce55fa940546c99221f3c3cb48?s=48&d=mm&r=g",
               "96":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d1451cce55fa940546c99221f3c3cb48?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
            },
            "acf":[  

            ],
            "_links":{  
               "self":[  
                  {  
                     "href":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
                  }
               ],
               "collection":[  
                  {  
                     "href":"https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/users"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

JS Code

```
const fetchNews = () => {
    var api = 'https://admin.headless-cms.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/29?_embed';

    $.ajax({
        url: api,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            if (response.length > 0 ) {
                $.each(response, function(i, post) {
                    var row = $('<div />').addClass('news__row');
                    var link = $('<a />').addClass('hide-for-small-only image-link zoom__container')
                                        .attr('href', post.link)
                                        .attr('title', post.title.rendered);
                    // var img = $('<img />');
                    var img = $('<div/>');

                    var section = $('<section />').addClass('news__details');
                    var small = $('<small />').addClass('news__entry-meta light');
                    var title = $('<p />').addClass('news__title bold');
                    var excerpt = $('<p />').addClass('news__excerpt');
                    var readMore = $('<a />').addClass('news__read-more').attr('href', post.link).attr('title', post.title.rendered).text('... Read More >');

                    // Featured image
                    $('.news__left a').attr('href', post.link);
                    // $(img).attr('src', post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url);
                    $(img).addClass('featured-image zoom__image');

                    var size;

                    if (i == 0) {
                        size = 'medium';
                    } else {
                        size = 'thumbnail';
                    }

                    $(img).css('background-image', 'url('+post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes[size].source_url + ')');
                    $(link).append(img);

                    // Details
                    var date = new Date(post.date).toDateString();
                    $(small).text(date);
                    $(title).text(post.title.rendered);
                    var excerptText = $(post.content.rendered).text().substring(0,75);  // Code in question
                    $(excerpt).text(excerptText);
                    $(excerpt).append(readMore);

                    $(section).append(small)
                              .append(title)
                              .append(excerpt);

                    $(row).append(link)
                          .append(section);

                    $('.lds-container').fadeOut();

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        if (i == 0 ) {
                            var firstStory = $(row).clone();
                            $('.news__left').append(firstStory).fadeIn();
                        }
                        $('.news__content').append(row).fadeIn();
                    }, 100);
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
    });
}

export { fetchNews };
```

There are no `<img />` tags in the excerpt text, but in the network tab it is downloading images found only in the full `post.content.rendered`.  I'm not outputting the the full content anywhere on the page either.

How do I stop it from fetching those images?

Comment: You’re going to want to post examples of `post.content.rendered`, along with what parts you don’t want. That way, people don’t need to know Wordpress to help you with a little jQuery code.

Comment: Also include whatever `readMore` is so people can determine if it’s problematic somehow. Generally, people helping on SO don’t like when a question includes variables that weren’t defined in the question. It leaves a lot of unknown out there.

Comment: @Nate Both have been added.

Comment: My guess would be that `$(post.content.rendered)` calls upon `document.createElement()`, since the content is interpretable as HTML. So you are actually creating a DOM element with the given image in it, even though you never show it. But I'm no jQuery expert..

Comment: @ViggoV I placed the content in there as using jQuery's .text() is the simplest way to strip HTML tags.  You may be right.  I will try setting the element to hidden first as then the browser shouldn't attempt to render it's content.

Comment: I don't think it needs to render in order to fetch the image. Basically `$()` says something like "I want to create a DOM element with this content, which i can then add to the DOM later". So the element does exist, it is just outside the DOM. That is the type of jQuery "magic" that is the reason I don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, I believe the offending line of code is `$(post.content.rendered)`. Since the content can be interpreted as HTML, jQuery will create a unmounted DOM element with all the contents. In other words the best solution is probably to strip the HTML tags in a different way.

One easy solution could be to use a regex, to simply remove everything inside angle brackets.

```
let string = '<p>My HTML content with an <img src="some://image.url"></p>'
string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

// output 'My HTML content with an '
```

The above regex is snatched from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140043/how-to-strip-html-tags-with-jquery), which also contains other suggestions. You could also write a regex to specifically strip image tags.

An important note is that, if `$()` really does execute the HTML, it is also a security risk as any `<script>` tags in the content might be executed.