# Shorten Multiple and Repetitive properties

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

(I have the similar problem earlier today but now, it's different). I have a code that creates an element, set attribute to them, and lastly, append to the parent div.

I already tried this:

```
Object.entries(selectorsByProp).forEach(([prop, selector]) => {
    document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = post[i][prop];
});
```

which actually works but it can only manipulate elements that shows and displays my data. What I need is that it has to create element, set attributes and append. Here's my ridiculous code...

```
var post = JSON.parse(this.response);
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var listcard = document.createElement("div"),
        imgcontent = document.createElement("div"),
        imgcntnr = document.createElement("div"),
        imglnk = document.createElement("a"),
        a = document.createElement("a"),
        img = document.createElement("img"),
        txtcntnt = document.createElement("div"),
        span = document.createElement("span");

    listcard.setAttribute('class', 'list-card');
    imgcontent.setAttribute('class', 'img-content');
    imgcntnr.setAttribute('class', 'img-container');
    imglnk.setAttribute('href', '#');
    img.setAttribute('class', 'thumb');
    txtcntnt.setAttribute('class', 'text-content');
    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    a.setAttribute('class', 'title');
    span.setAttribute('class', 'excerpt');

    img.setAttribute('src', post[i].img);
    img.setAttribute('alt', post[i].titles);
    a.innerHTML = post[i].titles;
    span.innerHTML = post[i].descs;

    imglnk.appendChild(img);
    imgcntnr.appendChild(imglnk);
    imgcontent.appendChild(imgcntnr);
    txtcntnt.innerHTML += a.outerHTML + span.outerHTML;
    listcard.innerHTML += imgcontent.outerHTML + txtcntnt.outerHTML;
    parent.appendChild(listcard);
}
```

```
<div class="list-card">
    <div class="img-content">
        <div class="img-container">
            <a href="#"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/182/135/?random" alt="" class="thumb"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-content">
        <a href="#" class="title">Lorem Ipsum</a>
        <span class="excerpt">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try a template engine like [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider inserting the HTML to insert all at once with `insertAdjacentHTML` instead, rather than (verbosely) creating and appending lots of elements. Use a template literal to keep things readable:

```js
const makeHTML = ({ img, titles, descs }) => `
<div class="list-card">
    <div class="img-content">
        <div class="img-container">
            <a href="#"> <img src="${img}" alt="${titles}" class="thumb"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-content">
        <a href="#" class="title">${descs}</a>
        <span class="excerpt">${descs}</span>
    </div>
</div>
`;

post.forEach((item) => {
  parent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', makeHTML(item));
});
```

Keep in mind that this code, like your existing code, assumes that the input is trustworthy. If it isn't, [strip the HTML tags first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140043/how-to-strip-html-tags-with-jquery), eg

```
const makeHTML = ({ img, titles, descs }) => {
  const safeImg = stripHTML(img);
  const safeTitles = stripHTML(titles);
  const safeDescs = stripHTML(descs);
  return `
    // rest of the template literal
    // which references safeImg, etc
  `;
};
```

Otherwise, you'll be allowing arbitrary script execution.

Comment: I appreciate your solution @CertainPerformance but I only need a number of items. Now all of the items in my json file are displayed.  Is there any solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: Slice the first 3 items from the array first: `post.slice(0, 3).forEach`

Comment: Once again, it works but with a little defect.  Since I have a for loop that ends at "i<3", it repeats the item 9 times. It's fine now after eliminating the loop. Thank you.