# How to get numbers in elements' inner text by javascript's regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to get numbers in the inner text of an html by javascript regex to replace them.
for example in the below code I want to get 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,1,2,3, but not the 444 inside of the div tag.

```
<body>
  aaaa123aaa456
  <div style="background: #444">aaaa123aaaa</div>
  aaaa123aaa
</body>
```

What could be the regular expression?

Comment: You can't (reliably):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: but regular expressions can find almost every sub string in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my old question:
It is possible to achieve it by lookahead.

```
/\d(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g
```

to replace the numbers

```
    html.replace(/\d(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g, function($0) {
        return map[$0]
    });
```

the source of the answer https://www.drupal.org/node/619198#comment-5710052

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to use `innerText` or `textContent` to get at the text without the tags and then just use the regex `/\d/g` to get the numbers.

```
function digitsInText(rootDomNode) {
  var text = rootDomNode.textContent || rootDomNode.innerText;
  return text.match(/\d/g) || [];
}
```

For example,

```
alert(digitsInText(document.body));
```

If your HTML is not in the DOM, you can try to strip the tags yourself : [JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string)

---

Since you need to do a replacement, I would still try to walk the DOM and operate on text nodes individually, but if that is out of the question, try

```
var HTML_TOKEN = /(?:[^<\d]|<(?!\/?[a-z]|!--))+|<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\/?[a-z](?:[^">']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>|(\d+)/gi;

function incrementAllNumbersInHtmlTextNodes(html) {
  return html.replace(HTML_TOKEN, function (all, digits) {
    if ("string" === typeof digits) {
      return "" + (+digits + 1);
    }
    return all; 
  });
}
```

then

```
incrementAllNumbersInHtmlTextNodes(
    '<b>123</b>Hello, World!<p>I <3 Ponies</p><div id=123>245</div>')
```

produces

```
    '<b>124</b>Hello, World!<p>I <4 Ponies</p><div id=123>246</div>'
```

It will get confused around where special elements like `<script>` end and won't recognize digits that are entity encoded, but should work otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i'm still wondering to find a regular expression which can find inner text of elements in a string.

Comment: Mike Samuel I need to replace the numbers, in your way i should use a function and call it over and over. but with regular expression  which   can parse all the html as a string I can replace numbers at once.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need RegExp to get the text contents of an element excluding its descendant elements' — in fact I'd advise against it as RegExp matching for HTML is notoriously difficult — there are DOM solutions:

```
function getImmediateText(element){
    var text = '';

    // Text and elements are all DOM nodes. We can grab the lot of immediate descendants and cycle through them.
    for(var i = 0, l = element.childNodes.length, node; i < l, node = element.childNodes[i]; ++i){
    // nodeType 3 is text
        if(node.nodeType === 3){
            text += node.nodeValue;
        }
    }

    return text;
}

var bodyText = getImmediateText(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
```

So here there's a function that will return only the immediate text content as a string. Of course, you could then strip that for numbers with the RegExp using something like this:

```
var numberString = bodyText.match(/\d+/g).join('');
```