# Unable to parse the JSON correctly

Tags: javascript, json

In the response of type `application/x-javascript` I am picking the required `JSON` portion in a varaible. Below is the `JSON`-

```
{
   "__ra":1,
   "payload":null,
   "data":[
      [
         "replace",
         "",
         true,
         {
            "__html": "\u003Cspan class=\"highlight fsm\" id=\"u_c_0\">I want this text only\u003C\/span>"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

From the references, which I got from Stackoverflow, I am able to pick the content inside `data` in the following way-

```
var temp = JSON.parse(resp).data;
```

But my aim is to get only the text part of `__html` value which is `I want this text only` . Somebody help.

Comment: do a `console.log(temp)` (assuming you're on a browser which provides that) and you'll see what you need to do.

Comment: Looks like it should be: `JSON.parse(resp).data[0][3]._html`

Comment: @MarcB: console.log(temp)=[
      [
         "replace",
         "",
         true,
         {
            "__html": "\u003Cspan class=\"highlight fsm\" id=\"u_c_0\">I want this text only\u003C\/span>"
         }
      ]
   ]

Comment: @RayViljoen: `http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/` is saying that JSON is valid

Comment: @ Ravi Joshi Tried it in the Chrome dev tools and it throws an exception.

Comment: I am in Firefox 19. No such error i am getting here.

Comment: @RaviJoshi: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string Best way without using jQuery.

Comment: @RaviJoshi I think you need to be clearer in your question about whether you always know your response will contain a `<span>` tag and it's the text within that which you want, or whether you are looking for something that will strip all HTML tags out of that string for you. Either way, you already have potential answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it all together:

```
var html = JSON.parse(resp).data[0][3]._html;
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;
var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
```

Kudos @Tim Down for this answer on cross-browser innerHTML: [JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string)

Comment: Nice non-jQuery solution... But it depends on whether the questioner is looking for just the text within a specific span or if it's text stripped of HTML. That much isn't clear yet. If it *was* clear, the questioner would get a +1 for me, and if it was general HTML tag stripping he was after, this would get a +1 from me too. And a vague sense of regret that I hadn't thought of it first! :-)

Comment: That's true.. @Ravi Joshi: Could you maybe explain whether it's the specific span tag or just the innerHTML in general you're after?

Comment: I like the way you get `text`... Cool.... Thanks man... [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string)is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to access the object you targeted:

```
var html = JSON.parse(resp).data[0][3]._html;
```

But then the output you want is **I want this text only**

The **html** variable doesn't containt that text but some html where the content you're looking for is the text inside a **span**

If you accept including jQuery in your project you can access that content this way

```
var text = $(html).text();
```

Comment: Thank you... can i go without jQuery? In that case how can i grab the text?

Comment: See accepted answer here for a non-jQuery solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string

Comment: @Ravi Joshi: - Yes, with a regular expression or other string parsing methods. But what kind of content are you going to get inside _html in the future? If you expect to receive some text ALWAYS inside a <span> go for the string parsing. If you are going to receive different html elements I'd suggest to go for jQuery

Comment: @Paolo But why bring in an entire framework just to examine one string. Why not use a plain old JavaScript solution?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to be a bit more specific with that data to get to the string of text you want:

```
var temp = JSON.parse(resp).data[0][3]['__html'];
```

Next you'll need to search that string to extract the data you want. That will largely depend on the regularity of the response you are getting. In any case, you will probably need to use a regular expression to parse the string you get in the response.

In this case, you are trying to get the text within the `<span>` element in the string. If that was the case for all your responses, you could do something like:

```
var text = /<span[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/span>/.exec(temp)[1];
```

This very specifically looks for text within the opening and closing of one span tag that contains no other HTML tags.

The main part to look at in the expression here is the `([^<]*)`, which will capture any character that is not an opening angled bracket, `<`. Everything around this is looking for instances of `<span>` with optional attributes. The `exec` is the method you perform on the `temp` string to return a match and the `[1]` will give you the first and only capture (e.g. the text between the `<span>` tags).

You would need read up more about [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to find out how to do something more specific (or provide more specific information in your question about the pattern of response you are looking for). But's generally well worth reading up on regular expressions if you're going to be doing this kind of work (parsing text, looking for patterns and matches) because they are a very concise and powerful way of doing it, if a little confusing at first.