# Using javascript and jQuery, parse to find then remove <p>Â&nbsp;</p> when found in html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a trusted source that sometimes returns html that contains this:  `<p>Â&nbsp;</p>` which is displayed in my page as "Â ". It has no `class` or `id` to help me select and remove it. I can't reliably use a descendant selector like `li > p` or add a `class` to the `p`.

Is there a way to parse the html page for `p` tags with matching content, then remove?

I found this solution to a similar problem but it's not working for me.  Perhaps it is the wrong approach for me: [JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string)

Comment: Sounds like you're running into Unicode characters that aren't being properly converted to the proper character set.  You should make sure your page is using the correct character set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document.body).html($(document.body).html().replace('Â', ""));
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vSem2/1/)

Comment: This has the side effect of removing any attached event handlers. That's not good.

Comment: Thanks! Great solution.  I must dig and study this code.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
$("p:contains(Â):not(:has(p))").remove();
```

Comment: As I understand it, the `Â&nbsp;` is the entire content of the `p`aragraph, and he wants to remove the entire `p`. Your previous solution was perfectly fine.

Comment: Bah, let me revert. Was unaware he wanted the entire element removed.

Comment: Be careful when using this approach with elements that can be nested - the selector must then be modified slightly, like `p:contains(Â):not(:has(p))`

Comment: Note that `p` elements _cannot_ be nested ;-)