# How to convert an HTML table to plain text and save it into a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was checking the site and found [JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string) but this doesn't really explains how to take this:

```
<tr id="element.incident.comments.additional">
<td colspan="2">
<span style="">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout:fixed" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<hr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="">
<td class="tdwrap"><strong>2014-01-23 14:45:40 - <a style="color:blue" href="sys_user.do?sysparm_view=itil&amp;sysparm_query=user_name=Superhero@superhero.com">SuperHero</a></strong></td>
<td align="right" nowrap="true"><sup>Additional comments</sup></td></tr>
<tr style="">
<td colspan="2"><span style="word-wrap:break-word;">received from: SDUperhero@superhero.com<br><br>lalalalalala
<br>lotsofwords<br><br><br><br><br><br>
The information transmitted, including any attachments, is intended only for the person or entity to which it is addressed and may contain confidential and/or privileged material</span></td></tr></tbody></table></span></td>
</tr>
```

and get the text inside:

```
<tr id="element.incident.comments.additional">
```

for further parsing.

I tried with

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
}

var commentsField = document.getElementById("element.incident.comments.additional").innerHTML;


alert(strip(commentsField));
```

but I'm not sure if this is the right way as I'm not getting anything in the alert.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You want .innerHTML(). values are for form fields.

Comment: @Diodeus I edited my code to reflect the new changes, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Have you tried jQuery.text()? am I missing something?

Comment: @Mabedan I tried:    

    var commentsField = document.getElementById("element.incident.comments.additional").text();

    alert(commentsField);


but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: It's a jquery method, so you will need to first create a jquery object. like so: `$(document.getElementById("element.incident.comments.additional")).text();` by the way, avoid using dots in your div id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `.` in your ids, you will need to escape them in your jQuery selector:

```
$("#txt").val($("#element\\.incident\\.comments\\.additional").html());
```

and that should work.

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/EQ9b3/

Comment: How would you make it so that it doesn't put the text inside the textfield and only into a variable?

Comment: `var iHtml = $("#element\\.incident\\.comments\\.additional").html();`

Comment: for some reason it's working on your jsfiddle but I see that the HTML is been formatted differently. I can't really change the HTML inside the code since I'm doing this using greasemonkey to enhance a website that my Service Desk uses (Service-Now) :/ I really don't know why it's not working

Comment: It seems that if I remove the <table> code, it will stop working.

Comment: I saw some tags were not closed. I tried and closed as many as possible, but nothing major. If your HTML is malformed, jQuery or JavaScript might not work with it altogether.

Comment: It seems that if I replace it with: 

`var iHTML = $(document.body).text();`

then it will work :S

Comment: It's not the most optimal way to do it but it's a workaround. Thanks a lot for the help!