# How to get text from site - server side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for easy way to get all visible text from site. I got HTML of this site and store it in "body" variable.

I found this solution:

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

And it works really good, but a lot of sites have javascript and css. I want to separate all text visible for normal user reading stuff on this page, so I must omit js scripts etc.

[I heard that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string) I can use jQuery, but in fact I can't because I use Node.JS ^^

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you read the accepted answer to the linked question properly, you will notice that it doesn't use any jQuery. But also note that your question is a bit different and far from trivial. For example, text could be hidden via CSS rules.

Comment: @FelixKling now, I must get text from site, later I will worry about CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js + "cheerio" module. Get the page, give it to cheerio and then $('body').text();

Comment: so, this is what I get when I tried to read text from duckduckgo.com: http://wklej.org/id/1259408/txt/ still returns javascript

Comment: Just do `$('script').remove();` beforehand. The chances are that you don't want *all* of the text in a page (menus etc), so you can target the interesting parts, `eg $('#content').text();`

What's nice is that you can open up the browser console on the page, and assuming the page used jQuery, play with the selectors to get what you want - I use `$('blah').css({ outline: '1px solid red' });` to highlight what the selector matches - then use those same selectors in you Node.js / cheerio code.

Comment: duckduckgo is all JS based. You'll need to open the page in PhantomJS first to get the final rendered page.

Answer (score 3):

I believe for anything non-trivial you might need an HTML parser. For example, have a look at [htmlparser2](https://npmjs.org/package/htmlparser2), I never used it myself but it looks like it could help you.

Answer (score 2):

I tested jsdom, Zombie.js and PhantomJS for a scraper I built. Although all three solutions yielded accurate results for most websites, PhantomJS was actually the most stable solution. read: it was able to consistently get good results even with the strangest websites out there. I stress-tested my application with a few hundred random websites (real world examples from previous input, not just a list of well known websites) and it seemed both the jsdom and Zombie.js solutions crashed or gave insufficient results on about 10% of these.

Because I needed stability and accuracy and my application only has to handle about 10 requests per minute I just spawn a phantom process for every website I want to check. Communication of results is done through stdio. I'm very pleased with this solution.

I must say I needed scripts to run so I couldn't use just a html parser. If you just want the text content and don't care about dynamically constructed pages I'd suggest you to look for a decent htmlparser like the one suggested in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some further research I found [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), which is almost what I need. I will try to do sth with it. If it achieve expectations I will paste some code there.