# Trim the HTML tags and character entites together Javascript Regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a regex in place that trims the html tags correctly:

```
/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g
```

But it won't trim the HTML character-enteties.
Can anyone please suggest a way to modify this regex to accomplish this task of mine?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with decoding the entities first and then removing them with regexp:

```
function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}

decodeHtml("&lt;p&gt;Hi&lt;/p&gt;");

"<p>Hi</p>"
```

Then using a simpler regexp would do the job: `/[<]\/?[^>]+[>]/g`

Does the job with `<p>Hi</p>` => `test`

Example in JS:

```
> var testString = "<p>Hi</p>"
> testString.replace(/[<]\/?[^>]+[>]/g,"");

< "Hi"
```

check also:

- [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)
- [JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string)

Comment: Hi @blaise: My scenario is:

If a user enters: <p>Hi</p>, it would trim <p> and <p> and just show Hi.

Also, if a user enters &lt;p&gt;Hi&lt;/p&gt;, it should again show Hi.

I hope that clears something?

Comment: Hi @CodeKaro hope this cover the use case you are facing.