# How to get the plain text from summernote editor?

Tags: jquery, html, css, summernote

for example, this is what I entered:

```
sdf
42342
xxcv
```

`.code()` converts it to `sdf<br>42342<br>xxcv`

or another thing:

```
[{"_type":"ServerOperation","operationType":"ANNOUNCE"}]
```

becames

```
<span class="message_content">[{"_type":"ServerOperation","operationType":"ANNOUNCE"}]</span>
```

how to get the pure / plain text?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could apply one of the top two answers for the question [JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string),  after the `.code()` to strip the tags.

ReactiveRaven's answer (to keep it to one line) works fine for me:

```
cleanText = $("#summernote").code().replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
```

For example, With `[{"_type":"ServerOperation","operationType":"ANNOUNCE"}]`:

- `$("#summernote").code()` returns

  > `<p>[{"_type":"ServerOperation","operationType":"ANNOUNCE"}]<br></p>`
- `$("#summernote").code().replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")` returns

  > `[{"_type":"ServerOperation","operationType":"ANNOUNCE"}]`

  without any tags.

---

And if you want to preserve the carriage return, you could replace `</p>` and `<br>` for a `\n` before applying the solution specified on the linked question:

```
$("#summernote").code()
                .replace(/<\/p>/gi, "\n")
                .replace(/<br\/?>/gi, "\n")
                .replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
```

Comment: yes, in the meantime I solved it with php's striptag

Answer (score 39):

Just try this:

```
var plainText = $($("#summernote").code()).text()
```

**EDIT**:
In newer versions you need use this instead:

```
var plainText = $($("#summernote").summernote("code")).text()
```

Comment: Formidable, and avoid regex on hmtl. This must be the accepted answer!

Comment: your answer might return a empty string. $('<textarea />').html($("#summernote").summernote("code")).text() is better!

Answer (score 5):

I needed to check if the textarea had any content. This have done the trick:

Current summernote version (8):

```
$($("#summernote").summernote('code').replace(/&nbsp;|<br>/g, ' ')).text().trim() == ''
```

In my older version:

```
$($("#summernote").code().replace(/&nbsp;|<br>/g, ' ')).text().trim() == ''
```

Comment: This is useful but it would not work as is. I had to change ".code()" to ".summernote('code')" for it to work properly.

Comment: In the current version, it appears to be as @AustinBest said. Here: https://hub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/assets/global/plugins/bower_components/summernote/README.html#api I found it my way in an older version. I believe the summernote API has changed, but I do not know in wich specific version.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this

```
   var code = $("#editor").code();
var text = code.replace(/<p>/gi, " ");
var plainText= $("<div />").html(text).text();
```

Comment: It is **very important** to wrap the content by a `div` like what you're doing here `$("<div />").html(text).text();`. Because if you the content of summernote contain some plain text and you don't wrap the whole content inside an HTML tag(like div) then, jQuery will through an error saying it was not expected.

Answer (score 2):

newer versions

```
var contents = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
var plainText = $("<p>" + contents+ "</p>").text();
```

Adding a dummy tag

resolves the lack of formatting.

Answer (score 1):

For version 0.8.20:

If you want the actual text, without any of Summernote's styling (bold, italic etc.) and without any linebreaks:

```
$("<div />").html($("#summernote").summernote("code")).text();
```

If you want the text, Summernote's styling and linebreaks:

```
$("<textarea />").html($("#summernote").summernote("code")).text();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This :)

```
$('#summernote').summernote ('code', '<b> hello world </ b>');
```

Comment: The question is how to get the text and about inserting the text