# Saving words from text into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to do an interesting task and currently have no idea how to do it.
I have a wiki page (ex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moldova ) and I want to save each word from this page into an array. Further I will need to parse this array to extract some specific words.

Can someone give me a hint how can I save words from a text into an array.
And how can I solve this problem:
-For each word remove punctuation such as ,.()"' etc.
-If the words is an html tag , don't store it.

Thank you.

Comment: for starters, you can do `words.split(' ');//returns array`

Comment: for words.split(' '); I will need to use simple javascript without no library ?

Comment: But how can I solve this problem? For each word remove punctuation such as ,.()"' etc. and -If the words is an html tag <Title>, don't store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `split()` method, it is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array. Read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

```
var text="your text";
var punctRE = /[\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]/g;
text.replace(punctRE, ''); // Strip all punctuation from the string.
var myArray=text.split(" "); // Pass an empty space as a separator.
```

Comment: for words.split(' '); I will need to use simple javascript without no library ?

Comment: But how can I solve this problem? For each word remove punctuation such as ,.()"' etc. and -If the words is an html tag <Title>, don't store it.

Comment: @Chris check the edit to my answer. I've provided a way to remove all punctuation.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but in case that var text="your text <title>"; with that code word "<title>" is still in that array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string 

That post should help you @Chris to achieve that