# How to remove HTML tags from Knockout Text binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, data-binding, foreach

So I have a foreach loop that displays your list of messages that contains the date sent/computed short message/computed short message/status. I tried binding the short message as an HTML data-bind, but that causes the issue of it bringing in the new line breaks since the message comes in from an HTML editor. So I thought maybe there is a way to use the text data-bind and just remove the HTML tags from it.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

HTML:

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered text-center">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="bg-success">
                                    <th width="15%" class="table-title" data-bind="click: sortMessageType" style="cursor: pointer">Message Type </th>
                                    <th width="25%" class="table-title" data-bind="click: sortSubject" style="cursor: pointer">Subject </th>
                                    <th width="40%" class="table-title" data-bind="click: sortMessage" style="cursor: pointer">Message </th>
                                    <th width="20%" class="table-title" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { sortDateCreated( $data, event ) }" style="cursor: pointer">Date Created </th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach: VisibleTemplates">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="mailbox-subject" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.selectTemplate( $data, event ) }, text: $data.MessageType"></td>
                                    <td class="mailbox-subject" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.selectTemplate( $data, event ) }, text: $data.ShortSubject"></td>
                                    <td class="mailbox-subject" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.selectTemplate( $data, event ) }, text: $data.ShortMessage"></td>
                                    <td class="mailbox-subject" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.selectTemplate( $data, event ) }, text: $data.DateTime"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Knockout:

```
 self.ShortSubject = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.Subject().length < 20) {
            return self.Subject();
        }
        else {
            return self.Subject().substring(0, 20) + '...';
        }
    });

    self.ShortMessage = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.Message().length < 50) {
            return self.Message();
        }
        else {
            return self.Message().substring(0, 50) + '...';
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would create a handler specific to this control.  In side the handler, you can manipulate the data, such as removing line feeds, or unwanted html, if I understand what you are asking.

Comment: Can we see some of your code?

Comment: Edited my entry to include the code for the foreach loop

Comment: Possibly Knockout extenders (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) could help you. Section "Live Example 1: Forcing input to be numeric" describes how to solve similar task - process entered value.

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem is removing the HTML from the input text. In knockout you can use [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html), or [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to process the entry and removing the tags before showing it.

The problem of removing tags can be solved in several ways. For example, you can use this solution: [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) (for example putting your text in a hidden or detached `div`), which is [explained in a different way here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string).