# knockout - remove html tag from title binding

Tags: knockout.js

How can we remove `<p>` tag originating from `tntDesc`?

```
<p class="desc" data-bind="html: tntDesc, attr: { title: tntDesc }"></p>
```

I want to be able to remove them from `title` binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to strip html tags from the value before it is bound to the attribute. See the snippet below (the code to strip the tags taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5002618/4602079).

A more fancy way would be to use ko.punches and implement stipTags as a text filter. See: https://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/

```js
var vm = {
  description: "<p>Hello world</p>"
}

function stripTags(input){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = input;
    return div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="html: description, attr: { title: stripTags(description) }"></div>
```