# Remove HTML tags in script

Tags: javascript, python, regex, replace

I've found this piece of code on the internet. It takes a sentence and makes every single word into link with this word. But it has weak side: if a sentence has HTML in it, this script doesn't remove it.

For example: it replaces '`<b>asserted</b>`' with '`http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/<b>asserted</b>`'

Could you please tell me what to change in this code for it to change '`<b>asserted</b>`' to '`http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asserted`'.

```
var content = document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML;

var punctuationless = content.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\؟^?&\*;:{}=\-_`~()”“"]/g, "");
var mixedCase = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g);
var finalString = mixedCase.toLowerCase();

var words = (finalString).split(" ");

var punctuatedWords = (content).split(" ");

var processed = "";
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    processed += "<a href = \"http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/" + words[i] + "\">";
    processed += punctuatedWords[i];
    processed += "</a> ";
}

document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = processed;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string)

Comment: You might want to escape the `.` in your regexp like `\.`, like you do with `\-` for instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex /<{1}[^<>]{1,}>{1}/g should replace any text in a string that is between two of these <> and the brackets themselves with a white space. This

```js
  var str = "<hi>How are you<hi><table><tr>I<tr><table>love cake<g>"
  str = str.replace(/<{1}[^<>]{1,}>{1}/g," ")
  document.writeln(str);
```

will give back " How are you I love cake".

If you paste this

```
var stripHTML = str.mixedCase(/<{1}[^<>]{1,}>{1}/g,"")
```

just below this

```
var mixedCase = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g);
```

and replace mixedCase with stripHTML in the line after, it will probably work

Comment: Thank you a lot for your efforts to help me. That was really valuable.

Answer (score 1):

```
function stripAllHtml(str) {
  if (!str || !str.length) return ''

  str = str.replace(/<script.*?>.*?<\/script>/igm, '')

  let tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
  tmp.innerHTML = str;

  return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}

stripAllHtml('<a>test</a>')
```

This function will strip all the HTML and return only text.

Hopefully, this will work for you

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Would you please tell me where to place this function in the script?

Comment: @МаксимЦіпан Anywhere you want just pass your HTML string to this function and use the returned result while making your URLs

Comment: @gaurav joshi Thank you a lot for you help and patience.

Comment: @МаксимЦіпан If this works for you then please add right Flag or upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

if you need to remove HTML tags And HTML Entities You can use

```
const text = '<p>test content </p><p><strong>test bold</strong>&nbsp;</p>'
text.replace(/<[^>]*(>|$)|&nbsp;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;|&gt;/g, '');
```

the result will be "test content test bold"