# How to get text data from froala editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, wysiwyg, froala

Currently I use `$('div#edit').froalaEditor('html.get')` to retrieve the html data inside editor, but it sucks when it comes to process / store the text data in my backend because of all the p tags and &npsb; symbols in raw html string.

To be honest they do not even pass to the database without losing parts of the data. Is there a way or an api to directly extract the text data as a string with proper symbols like "`\n\t`" from the froala editor?

Comment: Have you tried `$('div#edit').innerText`? See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5002618/826983

Answer (score 2):

1. If you dont like p tags you should use the [enter option](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/enter):

   ```
   $('div#froala-editor-br').froalaEditor({
     enter: $.FroalaEditor.ENTER_BR
   });
   ```
2. If you really would like to remove all tags you could use [jQuery text method](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

   ```
   jQuery($('div#edit').froalaEditor('html.get')).text()
   ```
3. Or you could use [HTML options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string-in-javascript/5002618#5002618)

   ```
   var html = $('div#edit').froalaEditor('html.get') ;
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.innerHTML = html;
   alert(div.innerText);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is http://textversionjs.com/ library which can be used to convert HTML to plain text. It also keeps new lines.

```html
<script src="textversion.js"></script>
<script>
  var html = $('div#edit').froalaEditor('html.get');
  var text = createTextVersion(html);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the easiest way to do this is

```
var body = $('#body').froalaEditor('html.get');
alert($(body).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplestst way to do it.

```
  <textarea  name="text"></textarea>
  <script>
    new FroalaEditor('textarea',{
      heightMin: 400,  // customize minimum hight
      heightMax: 250   // customize maximum hight
    });
  </script>

  or

  <textarea id="editor"  name="text"></textarea>
  <script>
    new FroalaEditor('#editor',{
      heightMin: 400,  // customize minimum hight
      heightMax: 250   // customize maximum hight
    });
  </script>
```

if you are using post method or get method put this code into form and you get this data as a request.POST['text'].

Answer (score -2):

You can use stringify() method in JSON to convert the HTML form to a text form.

```
<script>
    var html = $('div#edit').froalaEditor('html.get');
    var text = JSON.stringify(html)     
</script>
```

And you can store them in any backend and use them later.