# Removing malicious things from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, security, malware

I want to display a mail which is in HTML format in a web page.

I guess there are several malicious things in HTML which I should remove before displaying the HTML to the user.

The HTML mail comes from an unknown source and could be created by a evil hacker.

What needs to be done to call "clean" HTML from unknown source?

Malicious content (like "Parental Advisory explicit contents") are not part of this question. I just want to be sure the HTML can do any harm.

Answer (score -1):

You can serve html content using jquery `.text()` method and filter all html tags in order to remove them from final result so it does not look ugly for user.

What you are looking for is XSS protection. You will find more information about this issue here: [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

EDIT: Here you can find how to filter html tags: [JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string)

Comment: It's an HTML formatted email. Displaying the whole thing as source code would make most HTML emails unreadable. Stripping all the HTML out wouldn't be much better.

Comment: If email can contain anything -> tables, images, complex divs and so on, then I don't see any other options. He can always write some special filter system which would look for key words/sentences and include them in output. If email contains only text such as content, date, signature etc. then I would suggest just extract desired part of an email what would be way easier but I guess that's not the case.

Comment: It needs a sanitising filter based on a white list of safe markup (which allows things like `<p>` but not things like `onmouseover`).

Comment: Yea that would work. Also he needs to exclude img tags to prevent publishing uncensored stuff. just figured it out second ago but u were faster :P

Comment: No need to exclude images: "Malicious content (like "Parental Advisory explicit contents") are not part of this question."

Answer (score -1):

When using `jQuery`:

use `.text()` to escape HTML.

When using `PHP`:

use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape HTML. Don't be afraid of HTML tags visible in the browser, they are escaped.

Comment: It's an HTML formatted email. Displaying the whole thing as source code would make most HTML emails unreadable.

Comment: Thats why he should escape values, not whole E-Mails.

Comment: That doesn't help. The data is a whole HTML formatted email.