# New Google Calendar broke my script with HTML?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, calendar

My script gets calendar events for a range of dates and puts them in a Google Sheet. Then I can "print" the sheet to a PDF and send to the club members.
Club members need to book in to events by email. I tried to put "mailto" links in the calendar, but they were not clickable in the PDF, so I stopped doing that, and listed the email addresses as plain text.
Now  with the new Google Calendar, all email addresses put into Description fields appear as hypertext links. ("Inspect Element" shows things like

```
<a href="mailto:person@domain" target="_blank">person@domain</a> )
```

Some of these come through into the spreadsheet as hypertext links (a href="mailto: and so on), some just as the bare email addresses.
My script gets the calendar entries with

```
var events = cal.getEvents
    (new Date(StartMonth + firstDay + ", " + StartYear + " 00:00:00"),
    new Date(  EndMonth +  lastDay + ", " +   EndYear + " 23:59:59"));
```

and I get the Description out of the "events" array with

```
events[i].getDescription()
```

Do you know if a recent change to the type of the Description field of Google Calendar entries could be causing the problem?
Are there options to getDescription that could convert HTML to plain text?
Or, better still, is there a way to make clickable links in the PDF produced from the Google Sheet?
Thanks, Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know if a recent change to the type of the Description field of Google Calendar entries could be causing the problem?

This is due to the update to Google Calendar, initially released Oct. 2017, but which has been rolling out over the past couple months. Google added a text formatting feature (lists, bold, italics, links) to the event description field of the updated version. They are now pushing html tags through their calendar feeds. The update is causing [all sorts of problems](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/calendar/r3OC4cL53NQ;).

> Are there options to getDescription that could convert HTML to plain text?

Yes, but destructively. For the bare minimum, you could look into [removing the html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string) in javascript. You will lose paragraphs and line breaks this way. Another option is to use a library that can remove tags while preserving some of the plain-text/whitespace formatting, such as [textversionjs](https://github.com/EDMdesigner/textversionjs)

Comment: Pragmar, thankyou so much!
I got the code from textversionjs and added it to my Code.gs file and called it for each Description field, and the result is very good.
I tried to import it from the web at run time, but wasn't able to get that to work. Anyway, it's working now.
Thanks again, Jim