# How to filter out HTML tags from array and replace with nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

I have an array which outputs JSON in browser from API fetch so I have an obj like so:

```
locationArray =  dataArray.map(function(item){
                    return {
                    id: item.Id,
                    location: item.Location,
                    address: item.Address
                    };   
                 });
```

Can you Filter based on tags and replace tags with nothing on the address field ( i.e. no space and just remove):

`Tom<br>chased Jerry` would become `Tom    chased Jerry`.

I am trying this:

```
  var tags = ["<br>"];
    for(var i=0;i<locationArray.length;i++){
      if(locationArray[i].address === tags){
         locationArray[i].address = "";
      }
    }
```

In the browser the output address field has HTML tags like `<div>` or `<br>` and more but I want remove these tags how do I do that? I think my current example will remove all the string instead of just removing the tags.

Ideally remove all HTML or XML tags.

Also can this be done via ES6 syntax or jQuery?

NOTE:
Also to add this is from SharePoint API so returned data in browser is like so:
[image]

Comment: What value are you getting in locationArray[i].address?

Comment: I get back the correct address string but includes the HTML tags and the ASCII characters too which I am trying to remove and just have a readable address.

Comment: I've added new info on actual result to OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expression to filter out any html tag

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
for(var i=0;i<locationArray.length;i++){
     locationArray[i].address = locationArray[i].address.replace(regex, "");
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added new info on actual result to OP.

Comment: does it not working

Comment: Thank you! This is working!! Although in other posts people are scared of regex is it best practice??

Comment: address string are just too short to affect performance

Comment: It's about images breaking and security issues like script injection...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags or is this OK and not a big issue?

Comment: You are just stripping off html not extracting or anything, plus the size of an address string should relatively small, there shouldn't be big performance issue. If you really hit the performance issue you can always do progressive fixing or enhancement e.g improve algorithm, off load to worker etc. Personally i start off with simple solution and change when needed

Comment: Many many thanks for your answer and advice.

Comment: So cool bro, Thanks. added toString Method to convert it to string in my case i am using object. "locationArray[i].address.toString().replace(regex, "")"