# How to parse HTML content that is coming from angular JSON response

Tags: angular, tags, mailto

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am using the below mailto Code to populate to, cc, bcc, subject and body fields in email application. I am binding the parameters that is coming from JSON response as below. In the below code, contentField I am getting from response as HTML code with some 
 tags. I  need to remove the br tags and populate the fields in next line .

```
<a class="" href="mailto:{{toField}}?cc={{ccField}}&bcc={{bccField}}&subject={{subjectField}}&body={{contentField}}
```

Below is the HTML code from response and I am binding that to content in HTML.

```
'Please H F LUI DIGESTIVE AND LIVER CLINIC and +65 90119103 <br> 
Issues: </br><br>Doctor</br>MCR: 05572G'
```

**What I want to achieve is :**

'Please H F LUI DIGESTIVE AND LIVER CLINIC and +65 90119103
Issues:

Doctor
MCR: 05572G'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse HTML content using the below Regex as well.

```
// cleanText = strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
   cleanText = strInputCode.replace(/<.*?br.*?>/g, '%0D%0A');
```

[JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string)

Comment: With this code, I am just able to remove the br tags, but i want to bring them to next line as well. I have edited my question , what i want to achieve

Comment: You can try like this code "<br/>Some<br/> HTML".replace(/\<br\/\>/g, '\r\n');

Comment: Could u pls edit your original answer, I am getting clearly with your above comment

Comment: Updated original answer

Comment: That doesnt work . I am getting <br> tags also in my output : Please H F LUI DIGESTIVE AND LIVER CLINIC and  65 90119103 <br> Issues: </br><br>Doctor</br>MCR: 05572G

Comment: I placed alert after the code u have provided and it works fine . But when it opens in mail application , it shows like this : Please H F LUI DIGESTIVE AND LIVER CLINIC and  65 90119103  Issues: DoctorMCR: 05572G

Comment: May be you can try with ASCII Code '%0D%0A'. updated

Comment: Thanks Suresh ..the above solution works fine..but what s the role of ascii code here?

Comment: Outlook won't understand \r\n. We need to pass Ascii code for \r\n which will make  text displayed in next line.

Comment: I have some bold tags also inside the sentence. How do i parse those bold tags .   Something like this : '<b>Please H F LUI DIGESTIVE AND LIVER CLINIC</b> and +65 90119103 <br> 
Issues: </br><br>Doctor</br>MCR: 05572G'

Comment: Use this code cleanText = strInputCode.replace(/<.*?b.*?>/g, '');