# Regex for text between span with class tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've seen a lot of posts with regex for specific tags but what if a tag has a class or an ID or any attribute for that matter. How would I get just the text between the span tags. I have some places where the span and h tags doesn't have any class but most have.

```
const html = <h4><span  class="title">Lorem ipsum..</span></h5><h3><span id="bl">xvcxv</span>
```

I've tried this from another post but its not what I'm after.

```
html.match(/<span>([\s\S]*)(?=<\span/>)/g);
```

Comment: You could try some of the solutions in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks Doug but the regex in that link is for stripping tags out. I'm only looking to return text between the span tags.

Answer (score 2):

In your regex your are escaping the s like `\s` which turns its meaning into matching a whitespace character. Your regex will then match for example `<span>test< pan/>`

The closing span `<\span/>` should not contain a forward slash. The content is in the first capturing group, you can match the `<\/span>` instead of using a positive lookahead.

This part `[\s\S]*` is greedy meaning it will match until the last occurrence where `< pan/>` follows.

For your example data you could match not a closing angle bracket `<span[^>]*>`,  but is not advisable to [parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) using a regex. Another option could be to use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
const html = `<h4><span  class="title">Lorem ipsum..</span></h5><h3><span id="bl">xvcxv</span>`;
let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
doc.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(s => console.log(s.innerHTML));
```

Comment: As a variant, OP can insert his HTML into some `var div = document.createElement("div")` as `div.innerHTML = html`, and then just use `div.querySelectorAll("span")` as you've described :) Of course, if there is any DOM in OP's namespace

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance You are right, that is also possible.