# Strip HTML string by remove <p></p> tag and replace it by <br> in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a issue about strip HTML string.

I have a HTML string:

```
<p>I have a dog</p>
<p>I have a cat too</p>
<p>I have a lion too</p>
```

I want it become:

```
I have a dog<br/>
I have a cat too<br/>
I have a lion too
```

Comment: what have you tried? You seem to have enough rep to understand how this works. Please add a [mcve] to your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to strip HTML tags from string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't agree. That answer is old. Plus the given answer is much more elegant and precisely answers the question and sanitizes the input apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `textContent` of each `<p>`, then join by `<br>`:

```js
const input = `<p>I have a dog</p>
<p>I have a cat too</p>
<p>I have a lion too</p>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, 'text/html');
const output = [...doc.querySelectorAll('p')]
  .map(p => p.textContent)
  .join('<br>\n');
console.log(output);
```

Note that `<br>` alone [is sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br).

Comment: It's safer than actually creating an element, which can allow for arbitrary code execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**DOMParser**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```js
let str = `<p>I have a dog</p>
<p>I have a cat too</p>
<p>I have a lion too</p>`

let parser = new DOMParser()
let parsed = parser.parseFromString(str,'text/html')

let final = [...parsed.getElementsByTagName('p')].map(e=> e.textContent).join('<br/>')

console.log(final)
```

Note:-  Regex is not a suitable tool for HTML parsing, but in case just for learning purpose you want to see how to do it with regex

```js
let str = `<p>I have a dog</p>
<p>I have a cat too</p>
<p>I have a lion too</p>`

let op = str.split('\n').map(e=>e.replace(/<\/?p>/g,'')).join('<br/>')

console.log(op)
```

Comment: The exact same answer was give 5 mins ago.

Comment: @AvinKavish no answer was there when i started typing