# How to get the user-readable text of the body element from the website URL

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to extract the user-readable text from the body element of an html document in javascript. I get the html document of a website using XMLHttpRequest() and try to get the body text using innerText:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VTK654B/ref=ods_gw_bfw_H1_D_XPL2_mn_en?pf_rd_r=88S22KRX4KSFBBJAPXJM&pf_rd_p=c98ea2f1-9fa3-4bbb-9122-c5620c491f4f", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var res = xhr.response;
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(res, "text/html")
    console.log(doc.body.innerText)
  }
}
```

I have read that innerText is supposed to ignore the  and  tags and give only the visible part of the text. However when I am doing

```
doc.body.innerText
```

it includes the js code inside  tags. Is there a way to exclude these?

Comment: Just tested in my browser on this website. And I don't see any JS in the innerText. Could you add the HTML as an example and it might help.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question adding more context. I am trying to get the visible text of an amazon webpage using XMLHttpRequest() .

Comment: Check this out, might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string-in-javascript