# JS replace current tag with a new tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

So, I have some text that looks like:

```
<div class="content__main">
    <p>This is some text<br>
    This is another line<br>
    Third line goes here<br>
    How about one more</p>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is use JavaScript or jQuery to find the `<br>` tags and replace them with `</p><p>` tags. The content is auto-generated, so I can't just add it myself.

I'd like it to look like:

```
<div class="content__main">
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is another line</p>
    <p>Third line goes here</p>
    <p>How about one more</p>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.content__main').replace(/<br>\\*/g,"</p><p>"));
    });
</script>
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything, I think I'm pretty close though, can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Keep in mind that you https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Removed the dupe, OP doesn't want to replace a full opening and closing tag, but just replace the br with closing p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Changed `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll` with a `for of` to support multiple `class="content__main"` elements

---

###### Simple, unsafe way

You could just do the `replace` on the `innerHTML` and set that to the element.

```js
const d = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.content__main'));

for (let e of d) {
    e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/<br>\\*/g,"</p><p>");
}
```

```html
<div class="content__main">
    <p>This is some text<br>
    This is another line<br>
    Third line goes here<br>
    How about one more</p>
</div>
```

---

---

###### Safer way to prevent un-closed tags

A more safe way of doing this, to prevent missing a closing tag is to:

1. Get the `innerHTML`
2. Split on newlines
3. For each line;

   1. [Remove all the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string-in-javascript)
   2. [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the spaces
   3. [Create a `p`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and add the text
   4. [Insert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) that to the original `div`

```js
const d = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.content__main'));

for (let e of d) {

  let old = e.innerHTML;
  e.innerHTML = '';

  for (let line of old.split("\n")) {
    let cleaned = line.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "").trim();
    if (cleaned !== '') {
        let newE = document.createElement('p')
        newE.innerHTML = cleaned;
        e.appendChild(newE);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content__main">
    <p>This is some text<br>
    This is another line
    Third line goes here<br>
    How about one more</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have this running on a slideshow, if I use this code, it doesn't change all the slides (just the first one), so I selected an alternate answer that did change it for all the occurrences. I know I didn't disclose that, but I didn't think that'd be an issue. Thanks for helping though!!

Comment: Then you should change your question to show this. Kinda useless like this.

Comment: Hey there, I didn't think it'd be an issue, but I guess that's where part of my misunderstanding was to begin with...I think your solution would've worked fine if I didn't have things in a slideshow and your right I should've mentioned that from the start. I do appreciate the time you spent looking at this.

Comment: But my first snippet does the same as ryan's answer?

Comment: Yes and no. It works on the first item in my slideshow, but not all of them. Ryan's answer works on all of my slides. Not sure what the differences are, other than that.

Comment: Did you see my edit?

Comment: I'm sorry, I stand corrected. Your code does work. I apologize for missing that before

Comment: Noice, glad it worked! Gl implementing it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you're using `.replace` which is a JavaScript default string function on a jQuery object `$('.content__main')` - you need to get the HTML value of this as a string to do `.replace`.

You definitely don't need jQuery for this, but if you were using it the code could look as follows:

```
    $(function(){
        let current_content = $('.content__main').html();
        current_content = current_content.replace(/<br>\\*/g,"</p><p>")
        $('.content__main').html(current_content);
    });
```

Comment: Hey there, gave this one to @0stone0 since his answer came in first :-)