# append option to select menu?

Tags: javascript, html

Using Javascript how would I append an option to a HTML select menu?

e.g to this:

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SSwhr/

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Text";
option.value = "myvalue";
var select = document.getElementById("id-to-my-select-box");
select.appendChild(option);
```

Comment: Interesting, `option.text` definitely works, but I can't find any documentation on it (W3C, MDC, quirksmode, etc.).

Answer (score 18):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mySelect').append("<option>BMW</option>")

})
```

Comment: Doh! I *thought* the original question was tagged with jQuery.  But, also, as the only starting point was an html snippet, why not jQuery?

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) function:

```
const select = document.querySelector('select')
const value = 'bmw'
const label = 'BMW'

select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
  <option value="${value}">${label}</option>
`)
```

Answer (score 8):

#### HTML

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

#### JavaScript

```
 var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect'),
    newOption = document.createElement('option');

newOption.value = 'bmw';

// Not all browsers support textContent (W3C-compliant)
// When available, textContent is faster (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1359822/139010)
if (typeof newOption.textContent === 'undefined')
{
    newOption.innerText = 'BMW';
}
else
{
    newOption.textContent = 'BMW';
}

mySelect.appendChild(newOption);
```

***[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/GSSzz/3/)***