# How to add data asp:dropdownlist item on javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have  ajax function on aspx page.

```
 function fav() {

            var p = "3";

            var e = document.getElementById('<%= ddlCountry.ClientID %>');  
            var j = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

                //var aralik = p[1] + p[2];

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "STry.aspx/Fill",
                    data: "{'Param': '" + p + "','Param2': '" + j + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        //alert the error if needed              
                    },
                    success: function (msg) {

                        var data = msg.d;

                        if (data.indexOf(',') < 0)
                        {
                            document.getElementById('<%= ddlCity.ClientID %>').options.add(data);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data.split(",").forEach(function (item) {
                                var opt = document.createElement(item);
                                document.getElementById('<%= ddlCity.ClientID %>').options.add(opt);
                            });
                        }

                    }

                });

        }
```

the data return `var data = msg.d;` so, my return data is `data`. data type like this, if one more than;

> text1,text2,text3,text4

and i want to split this value and add dropdownlist that is `ddlCity`

this part is my try:

```
var data = msg.d;

      if (data.indexOf(',') < 0)
        {
          document.getElementById('<%= ddlCity.ClientID %>').options.add(data);
        }
         else
         {
            data.split(",").forEach(function (item) {
            var opt = document.createElement(item);
            document.getElementById('<%= ddlCity.ClientID %>').options.add(opt);
         });
```

but it is not working.

Briefly, I have a return data  like  (`text1,text2,text3,text4`)  how to add return data in `ddlCity` item on javascript?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data.split(",").forEach(function (item) {
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = item;
option.value = item;
var ddl= document.getElementById('<%= ddlCity.ClientID %>')
ddl.appendChild(option);
});
```

Check below
[append option to select menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182772/append-option-to-select-menu)

Answer (score 1):

**Using `forEach` as in your code snippet:**

*Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/63eX6/1/*

```
var data = "text1,text2,text3,text4";
var ddl = document.createElement("select");
ddl.id = "s1";
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(ddl);
data.split(",").forEach(function(item) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = item;
    opt.text = item;
    ddl.appendChild(opt);
});
```

1. Create a `select`, assign an `id` to it, and append it to an existing container like `div`,
2. Loop over the split array, create `option` element, assign `value` and `text` and then append it to the `select`.