# Populating HTML <select> values through GET Method

Tags: php, html

I need to populate a  with values from a repository in Qlik Sense. I am doing this in HTML, any ideas on how to do this without PHP?

I am new to this, so any help is appreciated.

UPDATE, Here is what I have tried that is not working. I expect the drop down list to be populated with a list of Stream names from the Qlik repository. This stream list can change at anytime, so my end goal is to have this drop down be automatically updated when the repository has been updated.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>Qlik Request Access</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gothic+A1" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img class="imgQlik" src="qlik-sense-logo.png">
    <hr>    
        <form action="mailto:emailAddress.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        <div>
            <table id="requestTable">
                <tbody>     
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdLabel">
                            <label>Name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="tdInput">
                            <input type="text" id="user-name" name="display-name" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]+" maxlength="50" minlength="2" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdLabel">
                            <label>Stream List:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="selectStyle" id="streamlist" name="streamlistselect">
                                <option value="streamRequest">
                                    <script> 
                                        qlik.callRepository('sa_repository(INTERNAL\sa_repository)').success(function(reply) {
                                        alert(JSON.stringify(reply));
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
                <input class="buttonRequest" type="submit" value="Submit Request">

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the issue you are facing. You could give this a read to know [how to ask questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: @thebrownkid , I have edited my question.

Comment: @Robert , I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to do it via JS then here is the solution from another answer:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Text";
option.value = "myvalue";
var select = document.getElementById("id-to-my-select-box");
select.appendChild(option);
```

This assumes that you are able to get the list from your "repo" via some AJAX request.

Original Answer:
[append option to select menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182772/append-option-to-select-menu)