# How I can set the value of a drop down list equal to the value from an input box and disable it for any further modification

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to set the value of a drop down list from the input box value and also trying to disable it. I am able to disable it but unable to set the value of it from the input box. Can anyone please help here.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>New Image VM Resource Group</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="IsAssociation" name="resourcegroupnull" value="New-Resourcegroup">New Resourcegroup</input>
    <select class="form-control" id="groupunderwriter" name="rgnames_option1">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Image VM Resource Group</option>
        <?php 
        foreach ($rgnames as $item) {
            echo "<option value='strtolower($item)'>$item</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Here is my JavaScript code.

```
$(document).on('change', '#IsAssociation', function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#groupunderwriter').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        let rgname = prompt("Please enter resource group name");
        if (rgname != null) {
            $('#groupunderwriter').val('rgname');
        }
    } else {
        $('#groupunderwriter').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Use .val() to set a value

Comment: @askwizard you can use `val()`, but this will only set the selected option if it ***exactly*** matches the input the user gives. Are you instead saying that you want to create a new option which contains the value the user types in to the `prompt()`?

Comment: No I wanted to only set the selected option based on the text entered in the input not the 2nd option, but I am trying with   $('#groupunderwriter').val(rgname);  and it's not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182772/append-option-to-select-menu and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570070/how-to-disable-enable-select-field-using-jquery seem to cover what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery val() property for set and get value for html selector

```
$('#groupunderwriter').append('<option selected value="'+rgname+'">'+rgname+'</option>');
$('#groupunderwriter').val(rgname);
```

Comment: '... and disable it for any further modification?'

Comment: I have changed the code as per your advice but this gives a blank text in the dropdown list. Please find the modified actual code.

Comment: please check, i have updated answer , now it will append option to select

Comment: `rgname` doesn't exist in the `select` when you are trying to use `.val()`. And the next line adds a 2nd option which is `selected` (*Select Image VM Resource Group* is already selected), and adds it without an actual `value` ...