# javascript If statement no working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is driving me crazy - basically this if statement is not working. The code keeps jumping into the else statement, I have hovered over the buttonText and everything seems alrite until it hits the conditions.

```
function DesignCodeViewClick(el) {

  $("div.divdesigncodeviewbuttonsselected").attr("class", "divdesigncodeviewbuttons");
  $(el).attr("class", "divdesigncodeviewbuttonsselected");

  var buttonText = el.innerText;

  if (buttonText.toLowerCase() == "design") {
      $("#iframecms").css("display", "none");
      $("textarea.divhtmleditor").css("display", "none");
  }
  else if (buttonText.toLowerCase() == "browse") {
      $("#iframecms").css("display", "block");
      $("textarea.divhtmleditor").css("display", "none");
  }
else {

      $("textarea.divhtmleditor").css("display", "block");
      $("#iframecms").css("display", "none");
      WebForm_DoCallback('SEOCMSControl1', 'getcode~http://www.triksportfolio.com', GetCodeServerResponse, null, null, true);

  }

}
```

Comment: What is the HTML? It could be that there are white space characters in the text such as new lines or spaces.

Comment: did you debug the value of buttonText or el.innerText?

Comment: You probably should use ".addClass()" and ".removeClass()" instead of ".attr()" to manipulate element classes.

Comment: If you are dealing with buttons, IE thinks the text content and the value are the same thing. jQuery's `attr()` method doesn't fix that, you may need to use the W3C `getAttributeNode()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) is the standard property. [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a Internet Explorer thing I believe. They are almost the same, but [not quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359822#1359822).

If you *did* want to do it that way, I'd suggest this...

```
var text;
if ('textContent' in el) {
   text = el.textContent;
} else {
   text = el.innerText;
}
```

**But**, you are using jQuery, however, so just use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

To ensure there is no leading or trailing whitespace, you can use jQuery's [`trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) utility function.

In addition, you are doing a few things jQuery can help you with. Look at [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Comment: @alex It exists two Methods: .innerText and .innerHTML. FF, Safari and Chrome in example supports these tags. 'text()' uses the same way as above.

Comment: @reporter I'm sorry, I'm not sure what your comment is about.

Comment: @alex innerText is the original Method. Ms has invented it, but all Browsers supports that. But you're right. for a clean code tthe op should use the jqery method

Comment: +1 shorter plain JS version: `var text = el.innerText || el.textContent`.

Comment: @reporter - read that "not quite" link Alex included in his answer.

Comment: @alex Hm, jQuery is available. Why not just: `$(el).text()`?

Comment: @Felix Don't know why I didn't think of that! Next time :)

Comment: @Pointy OOps I did oversee the almost invsible link.

Comment: @reporter - not all browsers support `innerText`, and jQuery's `text()` method doesn't use innerHTML or innerText (or textContent), it uses recursion to traverse DOM nodes and concatenates the values of the text nodes it encounters.