# Unable to change anchor.text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the text in the anchors as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) { 
  ...
  anchors[i].text = anchors[i].text + "+";
}
```

I tried alternative methods like `concat` and `append` but nothing works.

`anchors[i].innerHTML` helped but the code is called on DOMContentLoaded and I want to add only "+" string, instead of it I'm adding unpredictable sequence of "+"* e.g. "++++++++"

thank you for help

Comment: Go for JQuery. It can do this and much more and it works X Browser. :)

Comment: @user42540 What is the advantage of JQuery? Is the code faster?

Comment: [JQUERY IS REALLY GREAT AND DOES ALL THINGS](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, `HTMLElement.innerHTML` is for HTML strings. In your case, you're looking for `Node.textContent` and the non-standard `Node.innerText` since you're just replacing text.

```
var anchors = document.links;

for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++)
{
    var anchor = anchors[i];
    if(anchor.textContent)
    {
        //W3C DOM
        anchor.textContent += "+";   
    }else if(anchor.innerText)
    {
        //Microsoft DOM
        anchor.innerText += "+";   
    }
}
```

When dealing with older browsers, you can use a snippet like the one [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) provided here (do note that it will clear the childNodes clean and replace them with a text node):
['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359834#1359834)

Reference:

1. MDC:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent
2. MSDN:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
3. W3C DOM Level 3: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent

Comment: The problem with multiple "+" still remains.

Comment: Then your problem is one with event listeners (possibly bubbling). Try removing the event listener after the code executes.

Comment: I've tested it and it just adds one '+'. Are you running the code multiple times or are these links that already ended with '+' or does your `anchors` array contain more than one reference to each link? In any of those cases you would have to put a conditional statement in to make sure the string doesn't end with '+' before you add one.

Comment: @Matt McDonald I added removeEventListener and thought it helped but it not. But it speed up the code.

Comment: @Useless Code : The code runs on DOMContentLoaded event. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256653/javascript-code-too-slow-in-firefox-extension-using-storage-service/)

Comment: @xralf Yeah, I noticed that after I posted that comment and read Matt McDonalds comment.

Comment: Have you tried removing the listener **before** the loop? My guess is that every time a new '+' is inserted it is triggering another DOMContentLoaded event, so you would need to remove the event before you start injecting things into the DOM.

Comment: The problem was caused by other firefox extensions that probably generate page loads (I can't see) and about:blank page.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript DOM does not have .text. It has .innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the link text:

```
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
 for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].innerHTML += "+";
 }
```

Comment: A or a? i am a little confused :)