# Javascript code too slow in Firefox extension using Storage service

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm running the following javascript code in firefox extension

```
highlightLinks: function(e) {

  var anchors = e.target.getElementsByTagName("a");
  let file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
                  .get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
  file.append("test.sqlite");

  var storageService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/storage/service;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIStorageService);
  var conn = storageService.openDatabase(file);

  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var statement = conn.createStatement("select * from links where url=?1");
    statement.bindStringParameter(0, anchors[i].href);
    var visited = false;
    try {
      while (statement.executeStep()) {
        visited = true;
        break;
      }
    } catch (e) {
    } finally {
      statement.reset();
    }
    statement.finalize();
    if (visited) {
      anchors[i].innerHTML += "+";
    }
  }
  conn.close();
},
```

This function runs on DOMContentLoaded event. It checks for every link on the page if it's present in the `test.sqlite` database and markes the links that are present.

The problem is that the loading of pages is much slower now (especially when I lower CPU frequency). Could you help me make this code more efficient and resource saving?

Edit : Significant speedup was achieved by removing event listener at the and of the function.

thank you

Comment: How does the slowness manifest itself?

Comment: This doesn't answer your direct question, but if all you want to do is append '+' after all visited links it might be easier just to use CSS and the `:visited` selector and `:after` property.

Comment: @Sime Vias `content` should be HTML content of the web page.

Comment: @Chris Pebble. I want to append '+' after the links that are present in `test.sqlite`. If you can achieve this in CSS, please write more detail about it.

Comment: @xralf something like `a:visited { after: '+' }` would place a `+` symbol after every link the user has visited on the page but would not be able to read from the `test.sqlite` like you want it to. If all you needed was to decorate visited links the CSS would work but it looks like you need something more advanced.

Comment: @Chris Pebble thank you for tip, but you're right I need a little different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be faster if you pull the `createStatement` out of the loop, and reuse it, rebinding the parameters each time. The [docs for storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage) say: "Note: If you need to execute a statement multiple times, caching the result of createStatement will give you a noticeable performance improvement because the SQL query does not need to be parsed each time."

So instead of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var statement = conn.createStatement("select * from links where url=?1");
  statement.bindStringParameter(0, anchors[i].href);
  // ... do stuff with results
```

write:

```
var statement = conn.createStatement("select * from links where url=?1");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  statement.bindStringParameter(0, anchors[i].href);
  // ... do stuff with results
```

Edit: Also, if you're using a recent Firefox, you can use their asynchronous API to avoid delaying the UI. Instead of calling `executeStep`, use [executeAsync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mozIStorageStatement#executeAsync%28%29) instead.

```
statement.executeAsync({
  handleResult: function(aResultSet) {
    // ... do stuff with results
  },

  handleError: function(aError) {
    print("Error: " + aError.message);
  },

  handleCompletion: function(aReason) {
    if (aReason != Components.interfaces.mozIStorageStatementCallback.REASON_FINISHED)
      print("Query canceled or aborted!");
  }
});
```

Comment: The first code change ended with error `uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [mozIStorageStatement.bindStringParameter]" nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://highlighting/content/highlighter.js :: anonymous :: line 57" data: no]`

Comment: Could you please integrate it into my code? I don't understand how  how to use yet and if I should use both speedups or only the second.

Comment: I believe you need to pull the `statement.finalize()` out of the loop as well and call it just before calling `conn.close()`.

Comment: @Paul This helped. I speeded up the code with removeEventListener at the end of the function. So I can't recognize how much this change sped up. Could you please provide details to asynchronous execution yet?

Comment: Instead of everything in the try{}catch{}finally{}, call `executeAsync` and in your callback object, have something along the lines of `handleResult: function(resultSet) {if (resultSet.getNextRow()) anchors[i].innerHTML += "+";
}`

Comment: @Paul V Please, paste it into the code in the question. I don't know how to combine it with the existing code.

Comment: I replaced [this](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/620931/) code with [this](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/620930/) code but firefox was dead so I have to kill it.

Comment: That looks mostly good. It looks like you're querying for all the links in the database for every link in the page though. Keep the `"select * from links where url=?1"` and do `statement.bindStringParameter(0, anchors[i].href);` before the execAsync and I think you should be good.

Comment: Now strange error occurred "anchors[i] is undefined, Line 96". That's strange because it's defined, but maybe it lost variable scope or something.

Comment: Add as the first line of the for loop `let anchor = anchors[i];` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: It doesn't show any errors but "+" is not appended to anchors.

Comment: Can you post the current version?

Comment: btw. can I use some test or profiler to get know that the asynchronous version is faster? I upgraded to firefox 4 now and it's a little faster.

Comment: This mistake was solved in another question. The code is faster now, but I will try to ask for optimization of it yet. thank you

Comment: Fun fact: you should never *ever* use the synchronous version of the API.  The storage docs have big warnings about it, and you really should follow them.

Answer (score 0):

first tip, altough it won't save too much time, is not using anchors.length in the condition of the for-loop. better use:

```
for(var i = 0, num = anchors.length; i < num, i++) {...}
```

Comment: this is actually less of an issue with modern browsers.  Saw a recent post here recently on SO that showed that in some cases this is actually slower (trying to find it ...)

Answer (score 0):

In general when you call a database(not the browser ones) it is better to make one call, fetch all the data you will need into an array or an hash, and then work with them internally.

**EDIT:**

I would do that: load from the storage all the links and build a hash like:

```
linksHash = {
  'url-1':true,
   ...,
  'url-n':true
}
```

Then loop on `anchors` and make a check with something like:

```
if(linksHash[anchors[i].href]){
 //the link href is in the hash
}
```

Then if you note the RAM becomes an issue cut the load of the table in 2 or more pieces.

Comment: Thank you for advice. If you can, please, change the code I posted to be able to test if it is faster.

Comment: how large is the table links?

Comment: @Mic It has 4103 records now but will grow.

Comment: @Mic The problem is that the storage changes with another functions. Links are added and deleted.

Comment: If this does not go in further complications you can `delete linkHash[urlToDelete]` or `linkHash[urlToAdd] = true` to add it in this other function.

Comment: I still don't understand how to put it into the code in the question. I'm quite new to javascript.