# Problem with asynchronous database communication

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm communicating with sqlite database in firefox extension. First, I used [this](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/620931/) synchronous code. Then I changed it to [this](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/621586/) asynchronous code but it ended with error
`anchors[i] is undefined, Line 95`
[This](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/621160/) change didn't help.

There seems to be some problem with variable scope.

thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that `anchors` is apparently a node collection as returned by `document.anchors`. As such it isn't a fixed list, it will change if the document changes. It might happen that an anchor is removed from the document while your database query is running. To prevent an issue like this you can make a copy of the collection:

```
var anchors = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.anchors);
```

This will make `anchors` a regular array that won't change unexpectedly.

The other issue is that all your closure functions use the same variable `i` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures for more info). When `handleResult` executes `i` will have the value `anchors.length` because the loop is already finished. To prevent this you need to capture the "current" value of `i`, e.g. in the object property like this:

```
statement.executeAsync({
    anchorIndex: i,
    handleResult: function(aResultSet) {
        ...
        anchors[this.anchorIndex]
        ...
    }
```

Comment: anchors is `var anchors = e.target.getElementsByTagName("a");` the context of the code is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256653/javascript-code-too-slow-in-firefox-extension-using-storage-service) The function is called on DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: Same issue - `getElementsByTagName` returns a node collection that can change dynamically.

Comment: It can change dynamically but I think in 99 % it won't change, but it's good to know, so I will corret it in my code.

Comment: Of course it didn't help - now move the declaration of `anchorIndex` inside the object and maybe you won't get a syntax error any more.

Comment: Inside which object do you mean?

Comment: Just have a look at my code example. See where `anchorIndex: i,` line is located? Now compare with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I overlooked.

Comment: You can also get non-live NodeLists using https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll