# get text of Hidden <SPAN> in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 4 `<SPAN>` ,out of which 3 are hidden (`display:none`) in dynamic gridview

```
<tr>
   <SPAN id="Span1">Name</SPAN>
   <SPAN id="Span2" style="display:none"></SPAN>
   Id1<SPAN id="Span3" style="display:none">Id2</SPAN>
   <SPAN id="Span3" style="display:none">Id3</SPAN>
</td>
```

How could I get the text of those? I am getting that element in alert as `[object HtmlSpanElement]`. I had written it using `innerHtml` & `innerText` but result `undefined`.

Comment: Tip, id's can't start with a numeric char

Comment: This is shortcode. i am having too long character id's

Comment: Your sample code shows 3 spans, not the 4 you said you have. They're also not styled as display:none. You haven't shown the code you're using to get the [object HtmlSpanElement] either. Please revise your question.

Comment: @Bernhard Hofmann: I created gridview in some other .cs file, everything is dynamic. Thats why i written very clearly in question.this is shortcode. Try to tell me answer,why its not working in Mozilla

Comment: why have you tagged this with c#? it seems this is not a c# question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by poster, and with thanks to V4Vendetta

The code to get the text content of a none is:

```
var content = span.innerText || span.textContent;
```

This works because (in general) those browsers that don't support `innerText` do support `textContent`. [quirksmode has more detail](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t07).

Answer (score 0):

Using [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com), this would get the values:

```
$(function() {
   $('tr span').each(function() {
     alert($(this).text());
   });
});
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NRhzt/)

Comment: I know JQuery,but requirement is javascript

Comment: +1, it's correct and you didn't specify that it HAS to be plain JS, so no reason to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

USE:

```
var str = document.getElementById('span1').value;
```

Comment: Since those are label inside gridview.I can not able to manage their ids. I get that HtmlElement by grid.rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[0]

Comment: CellValue = grd.rows[1].cells[1].childNodes[0].value

Comment: same i follow. But i got childNodes[0] & no value.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers(Firefox) do not support `innerText` and would return undefined in such cases [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

One more way would be to check `textContent` but then its not suppoerted in IE

So i would suggest you to try `innerHTML` and not `innerHtml` (you have to be careful of the case) and this should work in all the browsers.

Comment: or you could do `span.innerText || span.textContent`?

Comment: @David Kemp:thanks.Post your comment as answer please. This is my accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Give your spans the Attribute `runat="server"` and access them like Span1.InnerHtml, Span2.InnerHtml, Span3.InnerHtml, etc. in CodeBehind. Or, considering that you get values from GridView, `((HtmlGenericControl)grid.rows[x].cells[y].FindControl("yourSpanId")).InnerHtml`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
 function MyFunction(){
     var gridview = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvmanageclients'); 
            var rCount = gridview.rows.length;
            alert(gridview.rows.length);
            var rowIndex=1;

            for (rowIndex; rowIndex<=rCount-1; rowIndex++)
            {
                var rowElement = gridview.rows[rowIndex];
                Cell = gridview.rows[rowIndex].cells[0];
                FirstControl = Cell.childNodes[0];
                alert(FirstControl.innerHTML);  

             }

  }
 </script>
```