# Image within div problem on firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, styles

I've got the following layout that is generated dynamically via jquery.  Basically it creates a bunch of divs with images in them, the divs are floated left. On Chrome and IE the image loads correctly, but on FireFox the images don't load.  If I try to inspect the image FireFox says the src failed to load.  Any ideas?

```
 <div id="divButton" class="buttonToolBar">
   <img src="..." alt="buttonType" />
 </div>

.buttonToolBar
{
    float:left;
    border-color: #CCCCCC #999999 #999999 #CCCCCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 1px 2px;
}
```

[image] vs [image]

UPDATE
This is an example of the url of one of the images
http://localhost:7499/CuteSoft_Client/CuteEditor/Themes/Office2007/Images/table.gif

UPDATE
I am using the ResolveClientUrl method on the server side to render the correct url, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using firebug to see what the response from the server is for those images?

Comment: Can you give an example image url ? also if you put the url in the browser does the image load ? (*in firefox*)

Comment: Side issue: Be careful of directly pinching icons from Word, or wherever they are from, they may not be licensed for this usage.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with ASP.NET or jQuery, it's just the handling of the image source URL. I need to see the actual URL itself exactly as it is written, or better, just compy paste the IMG tag "as it is"

Comment: I've added url to the question.  If I paste the url into FF it does load the image correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't a problem with the url, it was how I was getting it.  I was using the innerText property to get the url.  In FF the innerText doesn't work.

['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

I have see this happens on Firefox when you type the wrong slash on the images.

For example this works `/img/oneimage.jpg`  this **not** `\img\oneimage.jpg`

Comment: why the -1 ? hard to believe ?